# Enum ToString with user friendly strings

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

My enum consists of the following values:

```
private enum PublishStatusses{
    NotCompleted,
    Completed,
    Error
};
```

I want to be able to output these values in a user friendly way though.
I don't need to be able to go from string to value again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# String enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums)

Answer (score 447, accepted):

I use the [`Description`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) attribute from the System.ComponentModel namespace. Simply decorate the enum:

```
private enum PublishStatusValue
{
    [Description("Not Completed")]
    NotCompleted,
    Completed,
    Error
};
```

Then use this code to retrieve it:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue)
    where T : struct
{
    Type type = enumerationValue.GetType();
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("EnumerationValue must be of Enum type", "enumerationValue");
    }

    //Tries to find a DescriptionAttribute for a potential friendly name
    //for the enum
    MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString());
    if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            //Pull out the description value
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
    }
    //If we have no description attribute, just return the ToString of the enum
    return enumerationValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: just noticed the actual extension method never used the constrained type parameter.  fixed it to where the parameter uses the constrained type instead of object.

Comment: This example is easier to read.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415140/can-my-enums-have-friendly-names

Comment: I suspect there is a significant performance hit for using reflection as described in this solution.  The code for Will's method of using the ToFriendlyString extension method is much easier to understand, and its performance should be extremely fast too.

Comment: I like the version that @RayL linked as it will only add the extension method to Enums. If that's all you want to use this for (as indicated with the `ArgumentException`, then there's no reason to have the method be completely generic.

Comment: It does mean that every enum needs it's own extension method. This is more general use and does require more work, but you'd probably want to quantify what "fast" means before we decide on the performance.

Comment: Additionally, you could write some, potentially horrific, code to cache the values.  Since they're compiled in, you could statically cache the values of the description attributes in something like a static Dictionary<T, string> dictionary outside the extension method. Depends on your thinking around the code smell here.

Comment: @RayBooysen It works perfectly, but I cannot bind Description values to DropDownListFor. How to bind?

Comment: @christof, why can you not bind?  What issues are you seeing?

Comment: @RayBooysen Thanks for reply. Finally I managed to bind to Kendo DropdownListFor, but I am unsure if there is unnecessary part in .Bind section? `.BindTo(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MvcPWy.Enums.ReasonOfVisit)).Cast<MvcPWy.Enums.ReasonOfVisit>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.GetDescription(), Value = x.ToString() }))`

Comment: @christof, apologies I am not familiar with that component.  It looks fine, but does the Value property need to be a string?

Comment: @RayBooysen Actually Description value should be string.

Comment: Absolutely no point to making this method generic. Replace "this T" with "this Enum".

Comment: GetDescription() function is relevant just use MyEnum.MY_TYPE.ToString()

Comment: @petar that works but not if you want friendly strings to be displayed to users. MY_TYPE  will have the underscore and is not customisable.

Comment: IsEnum depends on the framework. I had to use `if(!type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)`

Comment: What is the significance of `struct` in the constraint on type `T`? Does this mean that all enumerator values come in as a `struct`?

Comment: Simply decorate the numb?  This looks like a horrifically complex way of mapping enums to a description string.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Insightful. Do you have another idea? Pop it in the answers so others can learn

Comment: We can use also `EnumMember` from `System.Runtime.Serialization`, if the string is more _symbolic_.

Comment: @humbads I am unable to find this "Will" or his solution.

Answer (score 435):

I do this with extension methods:

```
public enum ErrorLevel
{
  None,
  Low,
  High,
  SoylentGreen
}

public static class ErrorLevelExtensions
{
  public static string ToFriendlyString(this ErrorLevel me)
  {
    switch(me)
    {
      case ErrorLevel.None:
        return "Everything is OK";
      case ErrorLevel.Low:
        return "SNAFU, if you know what I mean.";
      case ErrorLevel.High:
        return "Reaching TARFU levels";
      case ErrorLevel.SoylentGreen:
        return "ITS PEOPLE!!!!";
      default:
        return "Get your damn dirty hands off me you FILTHY APE!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks for the input though. I put some remarks in noldorim's post regarding this solution.

Comment: This is so much cleaner than the Attribute answer.  Nice!

Comment: @pennyrave: Eh.  Lots of UI components are expecting to find and use DisplayNameAttribute and DescriptionAttribute.  In fact, now, I use these and an extension method to easily get those values out.

Comment: The issue I see with this is that you're constantly writing these extension methods.  With the attribute mechanism, it's a simple way of decorating it and only ever calling one method.

Comment: @RayBooysen: psst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring/479453?noredirect=1#comment13530613_479453

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @RayBooysen: Re: your comment, if you read up the list of comments (or click on that comment link) you'll see that I now agree with you.

Comment: More about extension methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx

Comment: I like this way, it's simple and the string values can be seen in the same file.

Comment: On a side not that code doesn't compile as there's no default for the switch statement, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071345/why-do-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-with-a-switch-statement-and-an-enum

Comment: @MoonWaxing fixed.  Also, note the "c#-like pseudocode" note in my profile.

Comment: @Panzercrisis it's a movie quote.  Search for it.  Also, damn damned damnit damn damn damnitol.  There.  No point editing it now.

Comment: It's better, in my opinion, to allow the `default` case implementation to return `me.ToString()` and only provide switch case statements for the enum values that you want to override. In your example, I get that they're all different but in actual use cases, I suspect that most of the single-word enum values will suffice and you'll only be providing overrides for multi-word enum values.

Comment: Make sure you follow up this design pattern with a unit test that dynamically gets the enum values to test and checks that newly inserted enums don't fall into the default unless you really meant for that to happen.  Seen way too often these big case statements get missed somewhere in the app.

Comment: This approach is better for strings, which should get translated.

Comment: I'm torn between this and the attribute answer, but I've used this in the past successfully.  It doesn't have the performance hit of Reflection, and you lose reflection when you take C# to Xamirin

Comment: For a multilingual solution this ist the best way

Comment: An extension method is also the best option if you don't have control over your enum declaration, like with a shared library or generated code.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Every time someone changes the `enum`, they have to remember to go to the extension method and change that too (very likely to run into bugs in the future). This answer violates **Open/Closed Principle** and the fact that it has got so many upvotes is a proof that most of us programmers know pretty much nothing about OO principles.

Comment: I totally agree with you @HoomanBahreini.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini A principle isn't a law. Sometimes they have to be defenestrated to be able to get something done in a sane way. I would argue that adhering to OO principles blindly is the actual problem of the current "programmer meta", not the opposite.

Answer (score 101):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what's wrong with Enum.GetName?

```
public string GetName(PublishStatusses value)
{
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(PublishStatusses), value)
}
```

edit: for user-friendly strings, you need to go through a .resource to get internationalisation/localisation done, and it would arguably be better to use a fixed key based on the enum key than a decorator attribute on the same.

Comment: I returns the literal value of the enum, not some user friendly one.

Comment: oic - well there's a pretty big case that you have to go through a string resource library based on this value then, because the alternative (decorator attribs) won't support I18N

Comment: In case of I18N I would make the GetDescription() method search in the resource lib for a translated string and fall back to the description and then fall back to the literal.

Comment: +1 for MyEnum.ToString() as the resource key for localization. i've been doing that for years

Comment: @annakata we've actually extended the attribute mechanism to include support for l18N, it's a simple change in fact.

Comment: Enum.GetName is just what I needed, decorator not required as well

Comment: Keep in mind that GetName is *very* slow if used in a tight loop in a busy app

Answer (score 29):

I created a reverse extension method to convert the description back into an enum value:

```
public static T ToEnumValue<T>(this string enumerationDescription) where T : struct
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (!type.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("ToEnumValue<T>(): Must be of enum type", "T");

    foreach (object val in System.Enum.GetValues(type))
        if (val.GetDescription<T>() == enumerationDescription)
            return (T)val;

    throw new ArgumentException("ToEnumValue<T>(): Invalid description for enum " + type.Name, "enumerationDescription");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but thanks for trying to be helpful! Though because this is a Q&A site, answers *should* be an attempt to directly answer the question. And the question specifically states "*I don't need to be able to go from string to value again.*" Once again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the positive criticism. It's always difficult being new to a site and learning about its culture and nuances. I am glad there are people like you who set the new guys straight. Once again, thanks for not dumping on the new guy.

Comment: @Jesse And 4 years later someone is happy to find bjrichardson code here! SO might be a Q&A site, but it doesn't mean the questions are dead after being answered.

Comment: @Jesse And 10 years later someone is happy to find Brian Richardson's code here!

Answer (score 20):

The easiest solution here is to use a custom extension method (in .NET 3.5 at least - you can just convert it into a static helper method for earlier framework versions).

```
public static string ToCustomString(this PublishStatusses value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        // Return string depending on value.
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am assuming here that you want to return something other than the actual name of the enum value (which you can get by simply calling ToString).

Comment: Although valid, I like the attribute way more. That way I can put my toSTring method in a seperate library, whilst putting the custom string representation with the enum itself

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose one advantage of this method is that you can include an argument with the method specifying some state variable, and then change what string representation is returned depending on this.

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the scope of the method I guess. While the Attribute way is more generic, your solution is more localized..  It's all about needs in the end.

Comment: You can put extension methods anywhere you want.  You just have to reference it where you want to use them.

Comment: Yes, but this would mean that this one extention method should be rewritten every time you introduce a new enum you want to have a friendly name for. This would also mean that ALL your applications would carry around friendly names for ALL your other applications...

Comment: CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Answer (score 13):

That other post is Java. You can't put methods in Enums in C#.

just do something like this:

```
PublishStatusses status = ...
String s = status.ToString();
```

If you want to use different display values for your enum values, you could use Attributes and Reflection.

Comment: toString is not safe in all cases - an enum with multiple entries with the same value (say for integer enums) will return the key of the first matching value, not the key of the item tested, this is why Enum.GetName is preferred

Comment: Well it was the easiest solution for his specific enum

Answer (score 12):

Some other more primitive options that avoid classes/reference types:

- Array method
- Nested struct method

**Array method**

```
private struct PublishStatusses
{
    public static string[] Desc = {
        "Not Completed",
        "Completed",
        "Error"
    };

    public enum Id
    {
        NotCompleted = 0,
        Completed,
        Error
    };
}
```

Usage

```
string desc = PublishStatusses.Desc[(int)PublishStatusses.Id.Completed];
```

**Nested struct method**

```
private struct PublishStatusses
{
    public struct NotCompleted
    {
        public const int Id = 0;
        public const string Desc = "Not Completed";
    }

    public struct Completed
    {
        public const int Id = 1;
        public const string Desc = "Completed";
    }

    public struct Error
    {
        public const int Id = 2;
        public const string Desc = "Error";
    }            
}
```

Usage

```
int id = PublishStatusses.NotCompleted.Id;
string desc = PublishStatusses.NotCompleted.Desc;
```

---

**Update (03/09/2018)**

A hybrid of Extension Methods and the first technique above.

I prefer enums to be defined where they "belong" (closest to their source of origin and not in some common, global namespace).

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class RecordVM
    {
        //public enum Enum { Minutes, Hours }
        public struct Enum
        {
            public enum Id { Minutes, Hours }
            public static string[] Name = { "Minute(s)", "Hour(s)" };
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method seems suited for a common area, and the "localized" definition of the enum now makes the extension method more verbose.

```
namespace Common
{
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string Name(this RecordVM.Enum.Id id)
        {
            return RecordVM.Enum.Name[(int)id];
        }
    }   
}
```

A usage example of the enum and it's extension method.

```
namespace Views
{
    public class RecordView 
    {
        private RecordDataFieldList<string, string> _fieldUnit;

        public RecordView()
        {
            _fieldUnit.List = new IdValueList<string, string>
            {            
                new ListItem<string>((int)RecordVM.Enum.Id.Minutes, RecordVM.Enum.Id.Minutes.Name()),
                new ListItem<string>((int)RecordVM.Enum.Id.Hours, RecordVM.Enum.Id.Hours.Name())
            };
        }

        private void Update()
        {    
            RecordVM.Enum.Id eId = DetermineUnit();

            _fieldUnit.Input.Text = _fieldUnit.List.SetSelected((int)eId).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** I actually decided to eliminate the `Enum` wrapper (and `Name` array), since it's best that the name strings come from a resource (ie config file or DB) instead of being hard-coded, and because I ended up putting the extension method in the `ViewModels` namespace (just in a different, "CommonVM.cs" file). Plus the whole `.Id` thing becomes distracting and cumbersome.

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class RecordVM
    {
        public enum Enum { Minutes, Hours }
        //public struct Enum
        //{
        //    public enum Id { Minutes, Hours }
        //    public static string[] Name = { "Minute(s)", "Hour(s)" };
        //}
    }
}
```

**CommonVM.cs**

```
//namespace Common
namespace ViewModels
{
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string Name(this RecordVM.Enum id)
        {
            //return RecordVM.Enum.Name[(int)id];
            switch (id)
            {
                case RecordVM.Enum.Minutes: return "Minute(s)";                    
                case RecordVM.Enum.Hours: return "Hour(s)";
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

A usage example of the enum and it's extension method.

```
namespace Views
{
    public class RecordView 
    {
        private RecordDataFieldList<string, string> _fieldUnit

        public RecordView()
        {
            _fieldUnit.List = new IdValueList<string, string>
            {            
                new ListItem<string>((int)RecordVM.Enum.Id.Minutes, RecordVM.Enum.Id.Minutes.Name()),
                new ListItem<string>((int)RecordVM.Enum.Id.Hours, RecordVM.Enum.Id.Hours.Name())
            };
        }

        private void Update()
        {    
            RecordVM.Enum eId = DetermineUnit();

            _fieldUnit.Input.Text = _fieldUnit.List.SetSelected((int)eId).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1-1=0 vote : This solution preserves the Enum syntax and does elegantly solve the problem without reflection or complex code, so +1 there. But it loses features of Enums themselves. So while IMO this is a good option, it doesn't answer the actual question and gets a -1. Net 0. Sorry we don't have a way to record that better in SO.

Comment: @TonyG Fair enough. After missing a few questions on pluarlsight.com's .net skill assessment I started to realize how in depth C# enum's are, so it's probably a good idea to at least know of their capabilities before deciding which methodology to apply (especially for pervasive usage, refactoring can be a bit of a time;).

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is just to include this extension class into your project, it will work with any enum in the project:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToFriendlyString(this Enum code)
    {
        return Enum.GetName(code.GetType(), code);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum ExampleEnum
{
    Demo = 0,
    Test = 1, 
    Live = 2
}
```

...

```
ExampleEnum ee = ExampleEnum.Live;
Console.WriteLine(ee.ToFriendlyString());
```

Comment: It's a mystery as to why this comment isn't the accepted one, or most upvoted - no reflection, no unnecessary attributes, ideal for simple situations where the enum is already nicely named. You could take this answer a step further and allow for adding spaces in-between capital letters before returning, 'My Enum'.

Comment: If the enum is already nicely named, there is no need for any extension method. Just use the existing ToString() method. `string result = "Result: " + ee;`

Comment: This should be the best answer.
It works for any enum.
You could even implement it using specific Enum just by changin the Enum type of the parameter to the Actual Enum on which to use it.

Comment: This answer and all of the comments ignore the original request for an extended description. You guys totally missed the exercise which is to return something other than the default ToString value. I won't downvote all of the notes for this answer here but I sure want to.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) package with [Humanize Enums](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-enums) possiblity. An eaxample:

```
enum PublishStatusses
{
    [Description("Custom description")]
    NotCompleted,
    AlmostCompleted,
    Error
};
```

then you can use `Humanize` extension method on enum directly:

```
var st1 = PublishStatusses.NotCompleted;
var str1 = st1.Humanize(); // will result in Custom description

var st2 = PublishStatusses.AlmostCompleted;
var str2 = st2.Humanize(); // will result in Almost completed (calculated automaticaly)
```

Comment: It uses reflection as well and is not cached. https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/2e45bca3d4bfc8c9ff651a32490c8e7676558f14/src/Humanizer/EnumHumanizeExtensions.cs

Comment: It will be as slow as the solution in the first answer by Ray

Answer (score 6):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Option One")]
    Option_One
}

public static string ToDescriptionString(this Enum This)
{
    Type type = This.GetType();

    string name = Enum.GetName(type, This);

    MemberInfo member = type.GetMembers()
        .Where(w => w.Name == name)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    DescriptionAttribute attribute = member != null
        ? member.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Where(w => w.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute))
            .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute
        : null;

    return attribute != null ? attribute.Description : name;
}
```

Comment: It's always nice to write some text explaining why this should work and why the OP's wasn't.

Comment: Just FYI, C# code conventions want local variables and method parameters with lower case initial letter. One exception is the `this` parameter in extension methods, that you can see called `This` in many examples in the web. Calling it like its type like you did (`Enum Enum`) make the code less readable.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using an enum use a static class.

replace

```
private enum PublishStatuses{
    NotCompleted,
    Completed,
    Error
};
```

with

```
private static class PublishStatuses{
    public static readonly string NotCompleted = "Not Completed";
    public static readonly string Completed = "Completed";
    public static readonly string Error = "Error";
};
```

it will be used like this

```
PublishStatuses.NotCompleted; // "Not Completed"
```

Issue using the top "extension method" solutions:

A private enum is often used inside another class. The extension method solution is not valid there since it must be in it's own class. This solution can be private and embedded in another class.

Comment: This will lose the value of `Enums` when passing to methods as all methods signatures will require `string` so anything could be passed; introducing the need for additional validation and decreasing general readability.

Answer (score 5):

With respect to Ray Booysen, there is a bug in the code: [Enum ToString with user friendly strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring/479417#479417)

You need to account for multiple attributes on the enum values.

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this object enumerationValue)
            where T : struct
    {
        Type type = enumerationValue.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("EnumerationValue must be of Enum type", "enumerationValue");
        }

        //Tries to find a DescriptionAttribute for a potential friendly name
        //for the enum
        MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString());
        if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0 && attrs.Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                //Pull out the description value
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs.Where(t=>t.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)).FirstOrDefault()).Description;
            }
        }
        //If we have no description attribute, just return the ToString of the enum
        return enumerationValue.ToString();
```

Comment: The omission of a check for multiple Description attributes is on purpose. If the enum has two, and you're using to to generate a description, I'd like to think that is an exceptional circumstance. I think the actual bug is I don't do a Single() to have an exception thrown.  Otherwise the whole method signature makes no sense. GetDescription()? Which description? An aggregate?

Answer (score 4):

Clean summary of the above suggestions with sample:

```
namespace EnumExtensions {

using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class TextAttribute : Attribute {
   public string Text;
   public TextAttribute( string text ) {
      Text = text;
   }//ctor
}// class TextAttribute

public static class EnumExtender {

public static string ToText( this Enum enumeration ) {

   MemberInfo[] memberInfo = enumeration.GetType().GetMember( enumeration.ToString() );

   if ( memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0 ) {

      object[] attributes = memberInfo[ 0 ].GetCustomAttributes( typeof(TextAttribute),  false );

      if ( attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 ) {
         return ( (TextAttribute)attributes[ 0 ] ).Text;
      }

   }//if

   return enumeration.ToString();

}//ToText

}//class EnumExtender

}//namespace
```

USAGE:

```
using System;
using EnumExtensions;

class Program {

public enum Appearance {

  [Text( "left-handed" ) ]
  Left,

  [Text( "right-handed" ) ]
  Right,

}//enum

static void Main( string[] args ) {

   var appearance = Appearance.Left;
   Console.WriteLine( appearance.ToText() );

}//Main

}//class
```

Comment: There is a [Description("")] attribute in C#, why not using this?

Comment: Of course using [Description("")]  is a way to go. But I wanted the sample to be complete.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to be a VB.NET fan, so here's my version, combining the DescriptionAttribute method with an extension method. First, the results:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel ' For <Description>

Module Module1
  ''' <summary>
  ''' An Enum type with three values and descriptions
  ''' </summary>
  Public Enum EnumType
    <Description("One")>
    V1 = 1

    ' This one has no description
    V2 = 2

    <Description("Three")>
    V3 = 3
  End Enum

  Sub Main()
    ' Description method is an extension in EnumExtensions
    For Each v As EnumType In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(EnumType))
      Console.WriteLine("Enum {0} has value {1} and description {2}",
        v,
        CInt(v),
        v.Description
      )
    Next
    ' Output:
    ' Enum V1 has value 1 and description One
    ' Enum V2 has value 2 and description V2
    ' Enum V3 has value 3 and description Three
  End Sub
End Module
```

Basic stuff: an enum called EnumType with three values V1, V2 and V3. The "magic" happens in the Console.WriteLine call in Sub Main(), where the last argument is simply `v.Description`. This returns "One" for V1, "V2" for V2, and "Three" for V3. This Description-method is in fact an extension method, defined in another module called EnumExtensions:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.ComponentModel

Module EnumExtensions
  Private _Descriptions As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

  ''' <summary>
  ''' This extension method adds a Description method
  ''' to all enum members. The result of the method is the
  ''' value of the Description attribute if present, else
  ''' the normal ToString() representation of the enum value.
  ''' </summary>
  <Extension>
  Public Function Description(e As [Enum]) As String
    ' Get the type of the enum
    Dim enumType As Type = e.GetType()
    ' Get the name of the enum value
    Dim name As String = e.ToString()

    ' Construct a full name for this enum value
    Dim fullName As String = enumType.FullName + "." + name

    ' See if we have looked it up earlier
    Dim enumDescription As String = Nothing
    If _Descriptions.TryGetValue(fullName, enumDescription) Then
      ' Yes we have - return previous value
      Return enumDescription
    End If

    ' Find the value of the Description attribute on this enum value
    Dim members As MemberInfo() = enumType.GetMember(name)
    If members IsNot Nothing AndAlso members.Length > 0 Then
      Dim descriptions() As Object = members(0).GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False)
      If descriptions IsNot Nothing AndAlso descriptions.Length > 0 Then
        ' Set name to description found
        name = DirectCast(descriptions(0), DescriptionAttribute).Description
      End If
    End If

    ' Save the name in the dictionary:
    _Descriptions.Add(fullName, name)

    ' Return the name
    Return name
  End Function
End Module
```

Because looking up description attributes using `Reflection` is slow, the lookups are also cached in a private `Dictionary`, that is populated on demand.

(Sorry for the VB.NET solution - it should be relatively straighforward to translate it to C#, and my C# is rusty on new subjects like extensions)

Comment: Alternate language solutions I'm sure are helpful for someone.  However, I just want to point out, for anyone seeing this in modern times, this answer is 10 years old and quite obsolete, at the time of this comment. The internal implementation of `ToString(string)` in modern versions of .net already avoids boxing _and_ caches results, so the manual implementation is unnecessary, these days, and likely less performant than the built-in methods.

Answer (score 3):

Even cleaner summary:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class TextAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Text;
    public TextAttribute(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}  

public static class EnumExtender
{
    public static string ToText(this Enum enumeration)
    {
        var memberInfo = enumeration.GetType().GetMember(enumeration.ToString());
        if (memberInfo.Length <= 0) return enumeration.ToString();

        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TextAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? ((TextAttribute)attributes[0]).Text : enumeration.ToString();
    }
}
```

Same usage as underscore describes.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enum.GetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netcore-2.2)

From the above link...

```
using System;

public class GetNameTest {
    enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };
    enum Styles { Plaid, Striped, Tartan, Corduroy };

    public static void Main() {

        Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Colors Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), 3));
        Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Styles Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Styles), 3));
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       The 4th value of the Colors Enum is Yellow
//       The 4th value of the Styles Enum is Corduroy
```

Comment: what if you want a different name the enumeration name, e.g. something with spaces.

Comment: Hi @StealthRabbi, I think that's been answered by another reply on this post here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/479417/1107715

Comment: @J.M.H What if you want localized name :>

Comment: If you're just getting the enum value name, why not simply call ToString("G") on it, rather than boxing and reflecting through the Enum.GetName methods? Microsoft recommends avoiding direct usage of System.Enum, because it _always_ boxes, and the internal implementation of ToString("G") on enums, in versions of .net since at least 6, but maybe even earlier, is an efficient one that caches results, so reflection only happens once per enum value. The `ToString(string)` method is in all .net versions back to framework 1.1 and standard 1.0, so it _is_ there and won't throw on a missing value.

Comment: @Whitebrim then an enum isn't an appropriate construct. Localization shouldn't be tied to low-level code implementation details like that. Use a more formal type or other more appropriate construct, if localized strings are what you want. One place this is a big fail in .net at least all the way to 7.0 is the DayOfWeek enum. It has 7 members., all named with the english names, and with Sunday as the 0 value. Not all cultures have 7 days in a week, nor do all cultures that _do_ have 7 use Sunday as the start of the week. Oops.

Answer (score 3):

I'm 7 years late for the party :-) But I'm sure this topic is visited frequently. 
 So I wanted to add a little sugar to the coffee:

What about the "F" format string specifier?

```
PublishStatusses[] ps = Enum.GetValues<PublishStatusses>();
ps.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.Write($"{c:F} "));
```

There is no need for any explicit function call.

In fact there isn't even need for any format specifier.
In case of a variable assignment to a string, ToString() does the work:

```
string foo = PublishStatusses.Error.ToString(); // or ToString("F")
```

And if it is about to insert spaces between words of a CamelCase string, you can just use a regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(foo, "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1")
```

Comment: Be careful with the F format string. It's intended for Flags enums, mostly, and may give you unexpected results if the value can be represented by a summation of multiple enum members, even without the Flags attribute. The G format string is the one that just gives the name of the matching member or, if not defined, the numeric value, and still works as expected with Flags enums (showing all flags that are set). See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings#f-or-f for an example of when F might act unexpectedly (DayOfWeek in that example).

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

According to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

It is possible to just convert a enumerator to string using a format like this:

```
public enum Example
{
    Example1,
    Example2
}

Console.WriteLine(Example.Example1.ToString("g"));

//Outputs: "Example1"
```

You can see all the possible formats in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Using the "g" (or "G") format string is the default behavior of an enum, as seen in the remarks on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_ToString).

Comment: This is a link to the format strings allowed for an Enum type. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings)

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, which is to provide a string that _doesn't_ match the enum member names, for user-friendly display. The most commonly-accepted method, and one that Microsoft themselves has examples of, is to use extension methods to provide custom formatting for enums, since System.Enum doesn't actually use the IFormatProvider in the `ToString(IFormatProvider)` method. The most efficient method tends to be an extension method with a switch expression returning strings based on the enum value and whatever other behaviors you may want to add on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use Newtonsoft anyway, you can do it as follows:

```
// Enum

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
   [EnumMember(Value = "User friendly value")]
   SomeValue=0,
}

// Usage as extension method

public static string ToDefaultString(this Enum enumValue)
{
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(enumValue).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an update to Ray Booysen's code that uses the generic GetCustomAttributes method and LINQ to make things a bit tidier.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute"/> on an struct, including enums.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the struct.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerationValue">A value of type <see cref="T:System.Enum"/></param>
    /// <returns>If the struct has a Description attribute, this method returns the description.  Otherwise it just calls ToString() on the struct.</returns>
    /// <remarks>Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring/479417#479417, but useful for any struct.</remarks>
    public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue) where T : struct
    {
        return enumerationValue.GetType().GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString())
                .SelectMany(mi => mi.GetCustomAttributes<DescriptionAttribute>(false),
                    (mi, ca) => ca.Description)
                .FirstOrDefault() ?? enumerationValue.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Failing to see why you need it to be generic?
If you're going to use reflection?

Comment: @LeeLouviere Mainly to avoid the boxing when the struct (value type) is passed as a parameter.

Comment: instead numerationValue.GetType() use: typeof(T).

Comment: Huge one-line improvement over accepted answer without (YMMV) losing readability. Yes, with typeof(T).

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to add a whitespace between the words, it is as simple as

```
string res = Regex.Replace(PublishStatusses.NotCompleted, "[A-Z]", " $0").Trim();
```

Comment: Reflection (implicit in enum->string conversion), regex, and multiple string manipulations all in one. Don't do this. It will create a lot of waste for the GC to deal with, at every call, and is about the heaviest solution (computationally) for this problem. Make an extension method with a switch statement for general use in your application or a method or property in the class you're using the enum in (if just one) to convert to user-friendly strings. If you want to make it future-proof, sure, you can do this in the `default` clause of the switch statement/expression, but I still wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a static class that simulate an enum:

```
public static class PublishStatusses{
   public const string NotCompleted = "Not Completed";
   public const string Completed = "Completed";
   public const string Error = "Error"
};
```

And to access the values, just use like an enum:

```
PublishStatusses.NotCompleted;
```

Comment: It's a different use case completely. This doesn't work with the same semantics as an enum, when passing as a method parameter. It will be a string, which is also a reference type (thus different behavior) on top of losing type/value enforcement/static analysis that an enum provides. Switch statements also become more cumbersome. Microsoft also explicitly recommends avoiding doing this in the design guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/static-class

Answer (score 1):

**2023**

```
public static string ToEnumString<T>(this T input) where T : Enum
{
     return Enum.GetName(typeof(T),input);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public enum CommentInformType { Abuse, Misleading, Spam, BadMouth }
...
CommentInformType _informType = CommentInformType.Spam;
_informType.ToEnumString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For flags enum including.

```
    public static string Description(this Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();

        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        var arrValue = value.ToString().Split(',').Select(v=>v.Trim());
        foreach (string strValue in arrValue)
        {
            MemberInfo[] memberInfo = type.GetMember(strValue);
            if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                object[] attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

                if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0 && attrs.Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                {
                    res.Add(((DescriptionAttribute)attrs.Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)).FirstOrDefault()).Description);
                }
                else
                    res.Add(strValue);
            }
            else
                res.Add(strValue);
        }

        return res.Aggregate((s,v)=>s+", "+v);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a generic class to store the enum/description pairs and a nested helper class to get the description.

The *enum*:

```
enum Status { Success, Fail, Pending }
```

The generic class:

**Note:** Since a generic class cannot be constrained by an *enum* I am constraining by *struct* instead and checking for *enum* in the constructor.

```
public class EnumX<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EnumX(T code, string desc)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new NotImplementedException();

        Code = code;
        Description = desc;
    }

    public class Helper
    {
        private List<EnumX<T>> codes;

        public Helper(List<EnumX<T>> codes)
        {
            this.codes = codes;
        }

        public string GetDescription(T code)
        {
            EnumX<T> e = codes.Where(c => c.Code.Equals(code)).FirstOrDefault();
            return e is null ? "Undefined" : e.Description;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
EnumX<Status>.Helper StatusCodes = new EnumX<Status>.Helper(new List<EnumX<Status>>()
        {
            new EnumX<Status>(Status.Success,"Operation was successful"),
            new EnumX<Status>(Status.Fail,"Operation failed"),
            new EnumX<Status>(Status.Pending,"Operation not complete. Please wait...")
        });

        Console.WriteLine(StatusCodes.GetDescription(Status.Pending));
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the best (and easiest) way to solve your problem is to write an Extension-Method for your enum:

```
public static string GetUserFriendlyString(this PublishStatusses status)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Someone was 7 years earlier to state that

Answer (score -3):

If you want something completely customizable, try out my solution here:

http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/post/Mapping-Enums-To-Strings-and-Strings-to-Enums-in-NET.aspx

Basically, the post outlines how to attach Description attributes to each of your enums and provides a generic way to map from enum to description.

Comment: And now the site is down.