# Why do "Not all code paths return a value" with a switch statement and an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, enums

I have the following code:

```
public int Method(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.Value1: return 1;
        case MyEnum.Value2: return 2;
        case MyEnum.Value3: return 3;
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}
```

And I get the error: `"Not all code paths return a value"`. I do not understand how that `switch` statement could ever not jump to one of the specified cases.

Can an `enum` somehow be `null`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There's nothing to say that the value of `myEnum` will be one of those values.

Don't mistake enums for being a *restrictive* set of values. It's really just a *named* set of values. For example, I could call your method with:

```
int x = Method((MyEnum) 127);
```

What would you want that to do? If you want it to throw an exception you can do that in a default case:

```
switch (myEnum)
{
    case MyEnum.Value1: return 1;
    case MyEnum.Value2: return 2;
    case MyEnum.Value3: return 3;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Alternatively you could use `Enum.IsDefined` upfront, if you want to do some other work before the switch statement. That has the disadvantage of boxing... there are some ways round that, but they're generally more work...

Sample:

```
public int Method(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    if (!IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), myEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
    }
    // Adjust as necessary, e.g. by adding 1 or whatever
    return (int) myEnum; 
}
```

This assumes there's an *obvious* relationship between the underlying values in `MyEnum` and the value you want to return.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Could you please point to an example of how to avoid boxing in such situations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: See https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/ for one example.

Comment: For the sake of anyone who might be misled, note that Jon's alternative suggestion to *"use `Enum.IsDefined` upfront"* won't make the compilation error go away; even though the compiler should perhaps *in principle* be able to figure out that you're exhaustively covering all possible enum values as long as you've got an `IsDefined` check in there, it isn't clever enough to actually do so. Although, since similar clever compiler tricks are starting to get implemented these days - like TypeScript's typeguards - perhaps we'll see the compiler become smart enough to figure this out in a few years.

Comment: @MarkAmery: With a call to `Enum.IsDefined`, you could then just cast afterwards though, rather than have a switch/case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't understand your reply, probably because I'm a big stupidhead who's just finding his feet in C#. Cast what to what, and how would that avoid a switch/case? `myEnum` is already of type `MyEnum`, so how can casting possibly help? Maybe adding an example of what you're suggesting to your answer would help, or maybe I'm just hopelessly thick.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, right. Yeah, I wasn't envisaging a scenario where the underlying value was meaningful or useful - I suppose in that case a cast would be reasonable, but it seems like an edge case to me.

Answer (score 5):

Enums are not limited to values they represent.  You can assign this:

```
MyEnum v = (MyEnum)1000;
```

And there would be no problem at all.  Add a default to your switch and you'll handle all possible situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the values in your enum (adding a fourth) your code will break.  You should add a default: case to your switch statement.

of course, the other way to achieve this would be to define the integer values in your enum...

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3
}
```

and then cast your enum as an int in code.  Instead of `int myInt = Method(myEnumValue);` you can use `int myInt = (int)myEnum`

Comment: The fact that my code breaks if I change it is not the compilers business right?

Comment: Not directly, no, but if you extend my answer with the others listed below you'll see the issue.  Bottom line -> add a default case to the code.

Comment: As much as I wish it was true that adding an enum value breaks my code, that is not the case.

Comment: to echo what Fax said, if I add a value to the enum and do not add a case to a switch based on that enum, I _want_ my code to fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyEnum blah = 0;
```

Default is always 0 and is implicitly convertible, even if you do not have one with a 0 value.

Answer (score -2):

It has to be either:

```
public int Method(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.Value1: return 1;
        case MyEnum.Value2: return 2;
        case MyEnum.Value3: return 3;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

or:

```
public int Method(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.Value1: return 1;
        case MyEnum.Value2: return 2;
        case MyEnum.Value3: return 3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or you can throw an exception in the case that the Enum is not a valid value, or any other handling case he desires.