# Not all code paths return a value in this function?

Tags: c#

System.IO.File.GetLength gives me the size of a file in bytes. What I'm attempting to do is take that size, in bytes, and convert it into the highest unit possible, without ever letting the size become less than 1. For example, instead of "2048" showing in the size column, I want "2 KB" to show. Here's the code:

```
 private string sizeDown(string size)
    {
        decimal sizeoffile = Convert.ToDecimal(size);
        int downed = 0;

        do
        {
            sizeoffile = sizeoffile / 1024;
            downed += 1;
        }
        while (sizeoffile > 1024);

        if (downed > 3)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            switch (downed)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " bytes";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " KB";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " MB";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " GB";



            }
        }
    }
```

However, as you probably see from the title, Visual Studio tells me that not all code paths return a value. I'm pretty confused. What value of size could result in my code not returning a value?

(By the way, I am aware that I take size as a string and then convert it into a decimal - I do that for convenience.)

Comment: what if `downed` is negative?

Comment: Remove the `if(downed > 3)` and add it as `default` to the `switch` statement.

Comment: else part deafult case is missing

Comment: You code will also not work with bytes. Remove the `do` keyword and replace it with the while. Or see my example.

Comment: A better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2071345/

Answer (score 0):

Change the below set of lines

```
if (downed > 3)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            switch (downed)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " bytes";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " KB";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " MB";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " GB";



            }
        }
```

to

```
        switch (downed)
        {
            case 0:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " bytes";
                break;
            case 1:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " KB";
                break;
            case 2:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " MB";
                break;
            case 3:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " GB";
            default : return ""; 

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add `break;` to `default` case as well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: you dont really required break if its the last statement .http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch

Comment: @KamleshArya, Thanks for sharing the inside about `break`

Comment: You really don't need to use break anywhere in a switch that you are using a return statement since the return will effectively break out of your switch and the break will never actually get hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with Switch....Case

```
 private string sizeDown(string size)
    {
        decimal sizeoffile = Convert.ToDecimal(size);
        int downed = 0;

        do
        {
            sizeoffile = sizeoffile / 1024;
            downed += 1;
        }
        while (sizeoffile > 1024);


            switch (downed)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " bytes";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " KB";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " MB";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " GB";
                    break;
                default:
                    return ""; 
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It removed the error. I was actually looking for something like "case else" also. Two birds with one stone, thanks!

Comment: "case else", it is already taken care in `default` case of `switch... case` statement

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error here is that the compiler has no way of knowing what value downed will be since it will be determined at runtime. You need to have a codepath for every value even if you know a runtime value will never hit it. As mentioned in other responses, you could add a default return value in your switch or you could throw an exception if it is a condition you don't expect to ever get hit.

```
switch (downed)
        {
            case 0:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " bytes";
                break;
            case 1:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " KB";
                break;
            case 2:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " MB";
                break;
            case 3:
                return Convert.ToString(sizeoffile) + " GB";

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your switch-case will return nothing when `downed` > 3. That is what causes the error. Second, your solution will fail for bytes. Remove the `do` keyword and replace it with the `while` statement.

To create a totally different answer compared to the rest:

```
private string sizeDown(string size)
{
    long sizeOfFile = long.Parse(size);
    if (sizeOfFile == 1)
        return sizeOfFile + " byte"; 
    if (sizeOfFile < 1024)
        return sizeOfFile + " bytes"; 
    if (sizeOfFile < 1024 * 1024)
        return sizeOfFile / 1024 + " KB"; 
    if (sizeOfFile < 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        return sizeOfFile / (1024 * 1024) + " MB"; 
    if (sizeOfFile < 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        return sizeOfFile / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) + " GB"; 

    return sizeOfFile / (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) + " TB"; 
}
```