# Enumeration values in a ComboBox

Tags: .net, enums

I have an Enumeration whitch values I want to aliment to a Combobox.

```
Enum SortType
  Id
  FirstName
  LastName
End Enum
```

I vant to associate to that enumeration some strings that I'll be able to set in the combobox. à la "Id", "First Name", "Last Name".

How should I proceed?

For advanced, I, eventually, should be able to internationalize that strings: ("Id", "Nom", "Prénom")

Actually, I have a `List(Of String) = new List("Id", "First Name", "Last Name")` and associate that list index to a enum value. This is a little embarrassing, because when I need to add or remove some enum values I should re-associate the indexes.

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums There are several approaches(C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these two questions:

[Enum ToString with user friendly strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring)

[How can I internationalize strings representing C# enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905342/how-can-i-internationalize-strings-representing-c-enum-values)

I'd go with [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905342/how-can-i-internationalize-strings-representing-c-enum-values/2905367#2905367) and put the string values in a resource file.

Answer (score 2):

In C# I usually use this code:

[How to Bind Enum Types to the Dropdown](http://geekswithblogs.net/jawad/archive/2005/06/24/EnumDropDown.aspx)

I think this code will run:

```
Friend Enum Speed
    Low = 1
    Medium = 2
    High = 3
End Enum

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    DropDownList1.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(Speed))
    DropDownList1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

Comment: +1. I usually add a little code to put spaces between CamelCase words. (FirstName -> "First Name")

Comment: I intentionally included two words enum names to see that the enum code name and GUI presentation name could differ. Say nothing for internationalization...