# missing return statement in factory pattern c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have the following code for my code but it always says the return statement is missing, even though I have put them in a switch list.

```
public IMap Map(string oldtheme) 
{ 
    switch (oldtheme) 
    { 
        case "archer": return new Archer(); 
        case "craftyblue": return new CraftyBlue(); 
        case "minimal": return new Minimal(); 
        case "mintalicious": return new Mintalicious(); 
        case "misfit": return new Misfit(); 
        case "peach": return new Peach(); 
        case "queen": return new Queen(); 
        case "sketch": return new Sketch(); 
        case "takeaway": return new TakeAwayLemonFresh(); 
        case "lemonfresh": return new TakeAwayLemonFresh(); 
        case "vanilla": return new Vanilla(); 
        case "velvet": return new Velvet(); 
        case "victoriana": return new Victoriana(); 
        case "writer": return new Writer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the case when `oldtheme` is none of the values you check for.

Depending on your case, I suggest throwing a [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception) so you **know** when it happens. I have added a [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) case to your `switch` statement:

```
public IMap Map(string oldtheme)
{
    switch ( oldtheme )
    {
        case "archer": return new Archer();
        case "craftyblue": return new CraftyBlue();
        case "minimal": return new Minimal();
        case "mintalicious": return new Mintalicious();
        case "misfit": return new Misfit();
        case "peach": return new Peach();
        case "queen": return new Queen();
        case "sketch": return new Sketch();
        case "takeaway": return new TakeAwayLemonFresh();
        case "lemonfresh": return new TakeAwayLemonFresh();
        case "vanilla": return new Vanilla();
        case "velvet": return new Velvet();
        case "victoriana": return new Victoriana();
        case "writer": return new Writer();
        default: throw new ArgumentException("unexpected value of oldtheme");
    }
}
```

Comment: I admit that this is actually better than just returning `null`, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

You lack a default value. Just add;

```
default: return null;
```

At the bottom of your `switch` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to return if the string is *none* of those you have in your switch? Your function is missing a return statement for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use break after every return command and it will work fine.

Comment: Hi Andre, that's not true. The `break` keyword is only necessary if the control can continue to the next `case`, which it can't because the execution is `return`ed. See [switch statement is return suitable to replace break](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3196163/1364007), for instance for a discussion.