# Custom define enum names for combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, enums

I have a namespace in which I have declared an enum as follows:

```
namespace IXMSoft.Business.SDK.Data
{
using System;

public enum BaudRate
{
    BR115200 = 7,
    BR19200 = 4,
    BR230400 = 8,
    BR2400 = 1,
    BR38400 = 5,
    BR4800 = 2,
    BR57600 = 6,
    BR9600 = 3
  }
}
```

When I retrieve these values in a combo box, which is in another namespace, using the statement

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(BaudRate.BR5700);
```

it shows the value as for example

> "BR5700"

I want to `remove BR in front and just want to display the value as "5700"`.
What should I do?

Comment: need to use `Replace` mmethod

Comment: Get the string before you add it into ComboBox1.String str=BaudRate.BR5700; if(str.contains("BR")) str=str.replace("BR","");Hope it helps you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I have an enum bound combobox with custom string formatting for enum values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-have-an-enum-bound-combobox-with-custom-string-formatting-for-enum-valu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) and an [appropriate extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932029/key-value-pair-as-enum/4932092#4932092) to read it out.

```
public enum BaudRate
{
    [Description("115200 kb")]
    BR115200 = 7,
    [Description("19200 kb")]
    BR19200 = 4,
    [Description("230400 kb")]
    BR230400 = 8,
    [Description("2400 kb")]
    BR2400 = 1,
    [Description("115200 kb")]
    BR38400 = 5,
    [Description("4800 kb")]
    BR4800 = 2,
    [Description("57600 kb")]
    BR57600 = 6,
    [Description("9600 kb")]
    BR9600 = 3
}
```

The extension method:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the string of an DescriptionAttribute of an Enum.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The Enum value for which the description is needed.</param>
    /// <returns>If a DescriptionAttribute is set it return the content of it.
    /// Otherwise just the raw name as string.</returns>
    public static string Description(this Enum value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        string description = value.ToString();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(description);
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
           (DescriptionAttribute[])
         fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            description = attributes[0].Description;
        }

        return description;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an List with all keys and values of a given Enum class
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Must be derived from class Enum!</typeparam>
    /// <returns>A list of KeyValuePair&lt;Enum, string&gt; with all available
    /// names and values of the given Enum.</returns>
    public static IList<KeyValuePair<Enum, string>> ToList<T>() where T : struct
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum");
        }

        return (IList<KeyValuePair<Enum, string>>)
                Enum.GetValues(type)
                    .OfType<Enum>()
                    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<Enum, string>(e, e.Description()))
                    .ToArray();
    }

    public static T GetValueFromDescription<T>(string description) where T : struct
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if(!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum");
        }

        foreach(var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;

            if(attribute != null)
            {
                if(attribute.Description == description)
                {
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(field.Name == description)
                {
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("description");
        // or return default(T);
    }
}
```

At the and you can simply apply this to your combo box by calling:

```
var list = EnumExtension.ToList<BaudRate>();
myComboBox.DataSource = list;
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

Comment: +1: much better than the hacks used in other answers, which are specific to this enum.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Agreed (quite fond of this answer), but OP did mention in another post that he was unable to modify the code for the enum.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: What if i dont have the desctiption tag? 
Is it still possible to show the value without BR?

Comment: @LeviBotelho: I can't make changes in the file as it is protected. Also the file does not have description tag.
Is there a way to do localization?

Comment: @Ankur You could make a wrapper class with an overriden ToString.

Comment: @AnkurSharma: If the file is protected there won't be any changes in the future. So you could also define your own enum `BetterBaudRate` that simply uses the same integer value for each baud rate. If you need to provide anywhere something of type `BaudRate` than simply cast it `BaudRate br = (BaudRate)myBetterBaudRate`.

Answer (score 2):

Example with string.replace:

```
BaudRate.BR115200.ToString().Replace("BR","");
```

Example with substring:

```
BaudRate.BR115200.ToString().Substring(2);
```

Comment: no problem, you should however consider removing BR altogether since you don't seem to need it! also, please mark as answer! :)

Comment: its actually a protected file. I can't make changes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the BR from the enum names seems like the most logical course of action. Given that your enum itself is named `BaudRate`, the BR is redundant. And given that it is present on *every* value, it doesn't add any descriptive power to the value name. And given that an enum value is always prefixed by the enum name, the result will always be clear (`BaudRate.9600` instead of `BaudRate.BR9600`).

If you can't/don't want to do this then you need to run a `BaudRate.XXX.ToString().Substring(2)` on each value before adding in order to remove the first two characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum BaudRate
{
    BR115200 = 7,
    BR19200 = 4,
    BR230400 = 8,
    BR2400 = 1,
    BR38400 = 5,
    BR4800 = 2,
    BR57600 = 6,
    BR9600 = 3
  }
}

foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(BaudRate))
{
    cmbEnum.Items.Add(name.Replace("BR",""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your combobox defined like as shown below :

```
<combobox>
   <ComboBoxItem>--</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>2400</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>4800</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>9600</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>19200</ComboBoxItem> // and soo on
</combobox>
```

and bind your Enum to the combobox