# selected enum value from combo list to enum property

Tags: c#, .net

On form load I load enum into combobox

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<VATMode> vatModes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VATMode)).
         Cast<VATMode>().ToList();           
    cmbVatMode.DataSource = vatModes;
}
```

Now I want do assign value from `cmbVatMode` (drop down list) to my enum property `MyCustomVatMode`

I tried with `MyCustomVatMode = cmbVatMode.SelectedValue;` but it doesnt work.

Comment: You should cast your `SelectedValue`

Comment: I prefer to use Enum.TryParse which returns boolean if the input value is parseable, or not.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom define enum names for combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767939/custom-define-enum-names-for-combobox)

Comment: @Oliver that's not a related question, though this must be asked several times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `DataSource` to a list of `VATMode`, `SelectedValue` will return a reference of type object. that can be successfully casted to your enum. Next code demonstrates this.

```
VATMode MyCustomVatMode = (VATMode)cmbVatMode.SelectedValue;
```

For example next code will print to console enum every time you will change a combobox:

```
cmbVatMode.SelectedValueChanged += (s, a) => 
{
    VATMode selected = (VATMode)cmbVatMode.SelectedValue;
    Console.WriteLine(selected);
};
```