# Enum to formatted string

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

```
public enum WebWizDateFormat
{
    DDMMYY,
    MMDDYY,
    YYDDMM,
    YYMMDD
}
```

```
public class WebWizForumUser
{
    public WebWizDateFormat DateFormat { get; set; }

    public WebWizForumUser()
    {
        this.DateFormat = WebWizDateFormat.DDMMYY;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(this.DateFormat);
    }
}
```

This works, but when I response.write it needs to come out in the format "dd/mm/yy", how can I do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken by default, the string representation of the enum is returned. I interpret the question now as you wanting to make it lower case and add slashes?

Comment: @Steven yes, declaring the enum type as dd/mm/yy doesn't work

Comment: In that case, simple string manipulations would work ofcourse, but consider using bobbymcr's answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is don't use an enum for this.  How about a static class?

```
public static class WebWizDateFormat
{
    public const string USFormat = "MM/DD/YY";
    public const string UKFormat = "DD/MM/YY";
}

// . . .
string dateFormat = WebWizDateFormat.USFormat;
```

(Just a sample, rename the fields to whatever makes sense for you.)

Comment: I don't really like dropping the use of enums here, but +1 because this abstracts out from MMDDYY, etc to "localized" formats.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just use a `Dictionary<WebWizDateFormat,string>` that you populate with corresponding string represenations for your enum, i.e.

```
DateMapping[WebWizDateFormat.DDMMYY] = "dd/mm/yy";
```

then you can just do

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(DateMapping[this.DateFormat]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules regarding this conversion are not clear. You could do something like that:

```
this.DateFormat.ToLower().Insert(4, "\\").Insert(2,"\\");
```

But I doubt, that is what you meant... ;-)
This could also be helpful to you: [Enum ToString with user friendly strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring)

Answer (score 0):

*Preamble:* I would advise against using an enum item name to represent data (you [can get the string name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) of a given enum value and type). I would also advise using implicitly assigned enum values as subtle changes such as adding or removing an enum item may create subtle incompatible changes/bugs.

In this case I may just create a map from an enum-value to a string format, such as:

```
public enum WebWizDateFormat
{
    DDMMYY = 1,
    MMDDYY = 2,
    YYDDMM = 3,
    YYMMDD = 4,
    // but better, maybe, as this abstracts out the "localization"
    // it is not mutually exclusive with the above
    // however, .NET *already* supports various localized date formats
    // which the mapping below could be altered to take advantage
    ShortUS = 10, // means "mm/dd/yy",
    LongUK = ...,
}

public IDictionary<string,string> WebWizDateFormatMap = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    { WebWizDateFormat.DDMMYY, "dd/mm/yy" },
    // "localized" version, same as MMDDYY
    { WebWizDateFormat.ShortUS, "mm/dd/yy" },
    ... // define for -all-
};

// to use later
string format = WebWizDateFormatMap[WebWizDateFormat.ShortUS];
```

Happy coding