# How to define an enum with string value?

Tags: c#, string, enums

I am trying to define an `Enum` and add valid common separators which used in CSV or similar files. Then I am going to bind it to a `ComboBox` as a data source so whenever I add or remove from the Enum definition, I would not need to change anything in the combo box.

The problem is how can I define enum with string representation, something like:

`public enum SeparatorChars{Comma = ",", Tab = "\t", Space = " "}`

Comment: FYI, there's a library dedicated to exactly this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumStringValues/ , which implements Amit Rai Sharma's solution

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can't - enum values have to be integral values. You can either use attributes to associate a string value with each enum value, or in this case if every separator is a single character you could just use the `char` value:

```
enum Separator
{
    Comma = ',',
    Tab = '\t',
    Space = ' '
}
```

(EDIT: Just to clarify, you can't make `char` the underlying type of the enum, but you can use `char` constants to assign the integral value corresponding to each enum value. The underlying type of the above enum is `int`.)

Then an extension method if you need one:

```
public string ToSeparatorString(this Separator separator)
{
    // TODO: validation
    return ((char) separator).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Char is not valid in enums. Msdn: "Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char."

Comment: @dowhilefor: You can use a char literal for the *value* though, as per my answer. I tested it :)

Comment: as this requirement is for files user may need CRLF separator. Will it work for that case too?

Comment: Thanks Jon, does \t counts as a char?!

Comment: @Maheep: No, in that case you'd want to use attributes instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh you are right, of course they can be casted to int. Nevermind.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: enums are just "named numbers" - so a string enum really doesn't fit in with that model at all.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Well, they're fairly different languages. I don't think you should expect everything from C# to be in TypeScript or vice versa.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: I would let it go, to be honest. It's not just C# - it's the whole of .NET that expects enums to be based on integers. So you'd be asking for a change to the CLR etc. The feature just wasn't designed for underlying string values, and the fact that TypeScript *does* have them 15 years after the CLR was designed doesn't really change that.

Answer (score 142):

You can achieve it but it will require a bit of work.

1. Define an attribute class which will contain the string value for enum.
2. Define an extension method which will return back the value from the attribute. e.g.`GetStringValue(this Enum value)` will return  attribute value.
3. Then you can define the enum like this..

   ```cs
   public enum Test : int {
       [StringValue("a")]
       Foo = 1,
       [StringValue("b")]
       Something = 2        
   }
   ```
4. To get back the value from Attribute `Test.Foo.GetStringValue();`

Refer : [Enum With String Values In C#](https://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/enum-with-string-values-in-c)

Comment: I know this old but it's obviously unique and allows you to use enums in code and string value in the DB. Amazing

Comment: Another late comment, but this is truly a brilliant solution

Comment: Keep in mind the performance hit from reflection, if that is relevant in your case.

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer!
Love the simplistic implementation.

Comment: FYI I implemented this exact solution into a Nuget package many years ago, so you can JustUseIt without worrying about implementing the backing Attribute and accessor methods (plus I added a little performance polishing and some extra bells and whistles) :D 

Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumStringValues/

Answer (score 103):

As far as I know, you will not be allowed to assign string values to enum. What you can do is create a class with string constants in it.

```
public static class SeparatorChars
{
    public static String Comma { get { return ",";} } 
    public static String Tab { get { return "\t,";} } 
    public static String Space { get { return " ";} } 
}
```

Comment: Down side to this approach opposed to others is that you can't enumerate these without doing something extra/special.

Comment: This doesn't help enforce certain values during compilation time, since `separator` is now a string (could be anything) instead of a `Separator` type with restricted valid values.

Answer (score 81):

For a simple enum of string values (or any other type):

```
public static class MyEnumClass
{
    public const string 
        MyValue1 = "My value 1",
        MyValue2 = "My value 2";
}
```

Usage: `string MyValue = MyEnumClass.MyValue1;`

Comment: While this isn't an enum, I think this might provide the best solution to what the user is trying to do. Sometimes, the simplest solution is best.

Comment: this is it for me

Comment: Too bad this enum is just a class with constants that you can't use in type annotations.

Answer (score 61):

Maybe it's too late, but here it goes.

We can use the attribute EnumMember to manage Enum values.

```
public enum UnitOfMeasure
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "KM")]
    Kilometer,
    [EnumMember(Value = "MI")]
    Miles
}
```

This way the result value for UnitOfMeasure will be KM or MI (In the deserialized response payload). This also can be seen in Andrew Whitaker [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391632/how-to-serialize-enums-to-different-property-name-using-json-net#answer-26391780).

[UPDATE]

Based on the comments below, some people may want to use the EnumMemberValue in C#. For that we can use the following extension:

```
    public static string? ToEnumMember<T>(this T value) where T : Enum
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .DeclaredMembers
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == value.ToString())?
            .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(false)?
            .Value;
    }
```

Now we can use it in C#.

```
var unitString = myEnum.Kilometers.ToEnumMember();
```

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: It doesn't work except during Serialization which is tiny part of enum use.
I wonder how many of the upvotes are due to SO locking the vote after 6 minutes.

Comment: Hi guys, based on your feedback, I have updated the response. Hope you find it useful. Cheers...

Answer (score 35):

You can't do this with enums, but you can do it like that:

```
public static class SeparatorChars
{
    public static string Comma = ",";

    public static string Tab = "\t";

    public static string Space = " ";
}
```

Comment: +1 While i think it's the right solution, i would change the name of the class or change the type to chars. Just to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell what will be the equivalent to `comboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum));` in this case?

Comment: @Sean87: I you want to have that, I would take JonSkeets answer.

Comment: I think this is almost the right answer, because it is not usable inside `switch-case` blocks. The fields should be `const` in order to. But it still can't be helped if you want to `Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum))`.

Comment: I would use `const` instead of `static`. Constants are read-only as well as static and are not asignable in constructors (unless readonly fields).

Comment: It is not very well. You should use static getter or readonly not public members!!!

Answer (score 24):

A class that emulates enum behaviour but using `string` instead of `int` can be created as follows...

```
public class GrainType
{
    private string _typeKeyWord;

    private GrainType(string typeKeyWord)
    {
        _typeKeyWord = typeKeyWord;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _typeKeyWord;
    }

    public static GrainType Wheat = new GrainType("GT_WHEAT");
    public static GrainType Corn = new GrainType("GT_CORN");
    public static GrainType Rice = new GrainType("GT_RICE");
    public static GrainType Barley = new GrainType("GT_BARLEY");

}
```

Usage...

```
GrainType myGrain = GrainType.Wheat;

PrintGrainKeyword(myGrain);
```

then...

```
public void PrintGrainKeyword(GrainType grain) 
{
    Console.Writeline("My Grain code is " + grain.ToString());   // Displays "My Grain code is GT_WHEAT"
}
```

Comment: The only thing is you can't do `GrainType myGrain = "GT_CORN"`, for example.

Comment: you could if you overide the operator

Answer (score 14):

It is kind of late for answer, but maybe it helps someone in future. I found it easier to use struct for this kind of problem.

Following sample is copy pasted part from MS code:

```
namespace System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     List of registered claims from different sources http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
    //     http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken
    public struct JwtRegisteredClaimNames
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Actort = "actort";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Typ = "typ";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Sub = "sub";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#OPLogout
        public const string Sid = "sid";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Prn = "prn";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Nbf = "nbf";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string Nonce = "nonce";
        //
        // Summary:
        //     http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4
        public const string NameId = "nameid";

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this aprroach is better than using a class?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli I don't exactly know why they use struct instead of class in MS for this kind of thing. I didn't even tried to find out, since this is perfectly working for me. Maybe try to ask question here on stack...

Comment: A struct should really only be used to represent a single value, is under 16 bytes, is immutable, and does not have to be unboxed frequently. This answer does not fit the criteria and should be a class. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

Comment: @JMD
1. This code is copy pasted from .NET.
2. It represents single value, it is immutable and is not being unboxed.
3. It might not be under 16B, but I don't see this as an issue given the way how this is intended to be used.

Comment: I understand it's copy/pasted from old examples. I'm just providing the new guidelines so people are not thinking this information is still correct. See the link I provided above for more information on why this answer is not in line with the current guidelines.

Answer (score 12):

You can't, because enum can only be based on a primitive numeric type.
You could try using a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead:

```
Dictionary<String, char> separators = new Dictionary<string, char>
{
    {"Comma", ','}, 
    {"Tab",  '\t'}, 
    {"Space", ' '},
};
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a `Dictionary<Separator, char>` or `Dictionary<Separator, string>` where `Separator` is a normal enum:

```
enum Separator
{
    Comma,
    Tab,
    Space
}
```

which would be a bit more pleasant than handling the strings directly.

Answer (score 10):

For people arriving here looking for an answer to a more generic question, you can extend the static class concept if you want your code to look like an `enum`.

The following approach works when you haven't finalised the `enum names` you want and the `enum values` are the `string` representation of the `enam name`; use `nameof()` to make your refactoring simpler.

```
public static class Colours
{
    public static string Red => nameof(Red);
    public static string Green => nameof(Green);
    public static string Blue => nameof(Blue);
}
```

This achieves the intention of an enum that has string values (such as the following pseudocode):

```
public enum Colours
{
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Blue"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a base class for creating string-valued enums in .NET. It is just one C# file that you can copy & paste into your projects, or install via NuGet package named [StringEnum](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StringEnum/).

### Usage:

```cs
///<completionlist cref="HexColor"/> 
class HexColor : StringEnum<HexColor>
{
    public static readonly HexColor Blue = New("#FF0000");
    public static readonly HexColor Green = New("#00FF00");
    public static readonly HexColor Red = New("#000FF");
}
```

### Features

- Your StringEnum looks somewhat similar to a regular enum:

```cs
    // Static Parse Method
    HexColor.Parse("#FF0000") // => HexColor.Red
    HexColor.Parse("#ff0000", caseSensitive: false) // => HexColor.Red
    HexColor.Parse("invalid") // => throws InvalidOperationException

    // Static TryParse method.
    HexColor.TryParse("#FF0000") // => HexColor.Red
    HexColor.TryParse("#ff0000", caseSensitive: false) // => HexColor.Red
    HexColor.TryParse("invalid") // => null

    // Parse and TryParse returns the preexistent instances
    object.ReferenceEquals(HexColor.Parse("#FF0000"), HexColor.Red) // => true

    // Conversion from your `StringEnum` to `string`
    string myString1 = HexColor.Red.ToString(); // => "#FF0000"
    string myString2 = HexColor.Red; // => "#FF0000" (implicit cast)
```

- Intellisense will suggest the enum name if the class is annotated with the xml comment `<completitionlist>`. (Works in both C# and VB): i.e.

[image: Intellisense demo]

### Instalation

Either:

- Install latest [**StringEnum**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StringEnum/) NuGet package, which is based on `.Net Standard 1.0` so it runs on `.Net Core` >= 1.0, `.Net Framework` >= 4.5, `Mono` >= 4.6, etc.
- Or paste the following StringEnum base class to your project. ([latest version](https://github.com/gerardog/StringEnum/blob/master/StringEnum/StringEnum.cs))

```cs
    public abstract class StringEnum<T> : IEquatable<T> where T : StringEnum<T>, new()
    {
        protected string Value;
        private static IList<T> valueList = new List<T>();
        protected static T New(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null; // the null-valued instance is null.

            var result = new T() { Value = value };
            valueList.Add(result);
            return result;
        }

        public static implicit operator string(StringEnum<T> enumValue) => enumValue.Value;
        public override string ToString() => Value;

        public static bool operator !=(StringEnum<T> o1, StringEnum<T> o2) => o1?.Value != o2?.Value;
        public static bool operator ==(StringEnum<T> o1, StringEnum<T> o2) => o1?.Value == o2?.Value;

        public override bool Equals(object other) => this.Value.Equals((other as T)?.Value ?? (other as string));
        bool IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other) => this.Value.Equals(other.Value);
        public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse the <paramref name="value"/> specified and returns a valid <typeparamref name="T"/> or else throws InvalidOperationException.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The string value representad by an instance of <typeparamref name="T"/>. Matches by string value, not by the member name.</param>
        /// <param name="caseSensitive">If true, the strings must match case sensitivity.</param>
        public static T Parse(string value, bool caseSensitive = false)
        {
            var result = TryParse(value, caseSensitive);
            if (result == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException((value == null ? "null" : $"'{value}'") + $" is not a valid {typeof(T).Name}");

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse the <paramref name="value"/> specified and returns a valid <typeparamref name="T"/> or else returns null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The string value representad by an instance of <typeparamref name="T"/>. Matches by string value, not by the member name.</param>
        /// <param name="caseSensitive">If true, the strings must match case sensitivity.</param>
        public static T TryParse(string value, bool caseSensitive = false)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            if (valueList.Count == 0) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(T).TypeHandle); // force static fields initialization
            var field = valueList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Value.Equals(value,
                    caseSensitive ? StringComparison.Ordinal
                                  : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            // Not using InvariantCulture because it's only supported in NETStandard >= 2.0

            if (field == null)
                return null;

            return field;
        }
    }
```

- For `Newtonsoft.Json` serialization support, copy this extended version instead. [StringEnum.cs](https://github.com/gerardog/StringEnum/blob/master/StringEnum.Sample.NewtonsoftSerialization/StringEnum.cs)

I realized after the fact that this code is similar to Ben's answer. I sincerely wrote it from scratch. However I think it has a few extras, like the `<completitionlist>` hack, the resulting class looks more like an Enum, no use of reflection on Parse(), the NuGet package and repo where I will hopefully address incoming issues and feedback.

Comment: In the latest version
    ' New("red") ' needs to be changed to ' Create("red") '

Answer (score 5):

What I have recently begun doing is using [Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

```cs
public static (string Fox, string Rabbit, string Horse) Animals = ("Fox", "Rabbit", "Horse");
...
public static (string Comma, string Tab, string Space) SeparatorChars = (",", "\t", " ");
```

Comment: Clever! Although, I can't immediately see the benefit over using a struct or class - am I missing something? I like it, but probably wouldn't use it because I find it harder to read. Thanks though!

Comment: I guess it's very terse, and if it's just for private code / a small number of values it's worth using.

Comment: I'm using this one as it's very clear what it does.  No need for extra methods, attributes, type conversions (e.g. ToString()), reflection, nor "newing up" anything.

Answer (score 4):

Building on some of the answers here I have implemented a reusable base class that mimics the behaviour of an enum but with `string` as the underlying type. It supports various operations including:

1. getting a list of possible values
2. converting to string
3. comparison with other instances via `.Equals`, `==`, and `!=`
4. conversion to/from JSON using a JSON.NET JsonConverter

This is the base class in it's entirety:

```
public abstract class StringEnumBase<T> : IEquatable<T>
    where T : StringEnumBase<T>
{
    public string Value { get; }

    protected StringEnumBase(string value) => this.Value = value;

    public override string ToString() => this.Value;

    public static List<T> AsList()
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T))
            .Select(p => (T)p.GetValue(null))
            .ToList();
    }

    public static T Parse(string value)
    {
        List<T> all = AsList();

        if (!all.Any(a => a.Value == value))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"\"{value}\" is not a valid value for the type {typeof(T).Name}");

        return all.Single(a => a.Value == value);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Value == other?.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj is T other) return this.Equals(other);
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();

    public static bool operator ==(StringEnumBase<T> a, StringEnumBase<T> b) => a?.Equals(b) ?? false;

    public static bool operator !=(StringEnumBase<T> a, StringEnumBase<T> b) => !(a?.Equals(b) ?? false);

    public class JsonConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
        where T : StringEnumBase<T>
    {
        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override bool CanWrite => true;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => ImplementsGeneric(objectType, typeof(StringEnumBase<>));

        private static bool ImplementsGeneric(Type type, Type generic)
        {
            while (type != null)
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == generic)
                    return true;

                type = type.BaseType;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken item = JToken.Load(reader);
            string value = item.Value<string>();
            return StringEnumBase<T>.Parse(value);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (value is StringEnumBase<T> v)
                JToken.FromObject(v.Value).WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you would implement your "string enum":

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<Colour>))]
public class Colour : StringEnumBase<Colour>
{
    private Colour(string value) : base(value) { }

    public static Colour Red => new Colour("red");
    public static Colour Green => new Colour("green");
    public static Colour Blue => new Colour("blue");
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Colour colour { get; }

    public Foo(Colour colour) => this.colour = colour;

    public bool Bar()
    {
        if (this.colour == Colour.Red || this.colour == Colour.Blue)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful!

Answer (score 4):

I wish there were a more elegant solution, like just allowing string type `enum` in the language level, but it seems that it is not supported yet. The code below is basically the same idea as other answers, but I think it is shorter and it can be reused. All you have to do is adding a `[Description("")]` above each `enum` entry and add a class that has 10 lines.

The class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringValue(this Enum en)
    {
        var type = en.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        var stringValue = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    enum Country
    {
        [Description("Deutschland")]
        Germany,
        [Description("Nippon")]
        Japan,
        [Description("Italia")]
        Italy,
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Show(new[] {Country.Germany, Country.Japan, Country.Italy});

        void Show(Country[] countries)
        {
            foreach (var country in countries)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(country.ToStringValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well first you try to assign strings not chars, even if they are just one character. use ',' instead of ",". Next thing is, enums only take integral types without `char` you could use the unicode value, but i would strongly advice you not to do so.
If you are certain that these values stay the same, in differnt cultures and languages, i would use a static class with const strings.

Answer (score 2):

While it is really not possible to use a `char` or a `string` as the base for an enum, i think this is not what you really like to do.

Like you mentioned you'd like to have an enum of possibilities and show a string representation of this within a combo box. If the user selects one of these string representations you'd like to get out the corresponding enum. And this is possible:

First we have to link some string to an enum value. This can be done by using the `DescriptionAttribute` like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828511/in-an-enum) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring).

Now you need to create a list of enum values and corresponding descriptions. This can be done by using the following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an List with all keys and values of a given Enum class
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Must be derived from class Enum!</typeparam>
/// <returns>A list of KeyValuePair&lt;Enum, string&gt; with all available
/// names and values of the given Enum.</returns>
public static IList<KeyValuePair<T, string>> ToList<T>() where T : struct
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum");
    }

    return (IList<KeyValuePair<T, string>>)
            Enum.GetValues(type)
                .OfType<T>()
                .Select(e =>
                {
                    var asEnum = (Enum)Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(Enum));
                    return new KeyValuePair<T, string>(e, asEnum.Description());
                })
                .ToArray();
}
```

Now you'll have a list of key value pairs of all enums and their description. So let's simply assign this as a data source for a combo box.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox.DataSource = EnumUtilities.ToList<Separator>();

comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    var selectedEnum = (Separator)comboBox.SelectedValue;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedEnum.ToString());
}
```

The user sees all the string representations of the enum and within your code you'll get the desired enum value.

Answer (score 2):

Adding still something more as some of the answers here are missing the point of using enums. Naturally one option is is to have well defined strings as static variables etc, but then you're opening your interface for illegal values also, i.e. you need to validate the input. With enums it's guaranteed that only allowed values are passed to your interface.

```
enum Separator
{
    Comma,
    Tab,
    Space,
    CRLF,
    SoFunny
}
```

In addition to this you can use e.g. an internal Dictionary for the mapping purposes.

```
    private readonly Dictionary<Separator, string> separatorMap = new Dictionary<Separator, string>()
    {
        { Separator.Comma, "," },
        { Separator.Tab, "\t" },
        { Separator.Space, " " },
        { Separator.CRLF, "\r\n" },
        { Separator.SoFunny, "Your Mom" }
    };
```

Even more sophisticated method for doing this is to create a [static class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-create-a-new-method-for-an-enumeration) to give the enum new capabilities and handle the mapping there.

Example of using code above would be like.

```
public string TransformToSingleString(List<string> values, Separator separator)
{
    var separateWith = separatorMap[separator];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Enumaration Class

```
 public sealed class GenericDateTimeFormatType
    {

        public static readonly GenericDateTimeFormatType Format1 = new GenericDateTimeFormatType("dd-MM-YYYY");
        public static readonly GenericDateTimeFormatType Format2 = new GenericDateTimeFormatType("dd-MMM-YYYY");

        private GenericDateTimeFormatType(string Format)
        {
            _Value = Format;
        }

        public string _Value { get; private set; }
    }
```

> Enumaration Consuption

```
public static void Main()
{
       Country A = new Country();

       A.DefaultDateFormat = GenericDateTimeFormatType.Format1;

      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't define enumeration as string type. The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

If you need more details on enumeration please follow below link,that link will help you to understand enumeration.
[Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

@narendras1414

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

```
   public class ShapeTypes
    {
        private ShapeTypes() { }
        public static string OVAL
        {
            get
            {
                return "ov";
            }
            private set { }
        }

        public static string SQUARE
        {
            get
            {
                return "sq";
            }
            private set { }
        }

        public static string RECTANGLE
        {
            get
            {
                return "rec";
            }
            private set { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Way after the party but for anyone stumbling across this SO posting, you could always fashion something customized like this, where you could match your "simulated" `enum` types like you do with regular `enums` and also access the "underlying" `string` value via `MyEnumObject.Value`:

```
public class MyEnumType
{
    public readonly string Value;

    public static readonly MyEnumType MyStringEnum1 = new MyEnumType("String 1");
    public static readonly MyEnumType MyStringEnum2 = new MyEnumType("String 2");
    public static readonly MyEnumType MyStringEnum3 = new MyEnumType("String 3");
    public static readonly MyEnumType MyStringEnum4 = new MyEnumType("String 4");

    private MyEnumType(string value)
    { this.Value = value; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public string? MyStringEnumMethod(MyEnumType enumObj)
{
    switch (enumObj)
    {
        case MyEnumType.MyStringEnum1:
            //Do something
            return enumObj.Value;
        case MyEnumType.MyStringEnum3:
            //Do something else
            return enumObj.Value;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```