# Compare string array to enum C#(UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I compare the string data i use to my enum

I made this enum

```
public enum BeadColor
{
    BLUE,
    RED,
    GREEN,
    NONE,
}

public BeadColor previousColor = BeadColor.NONE;
```

and I will create a string array like this

```
string str = {"P", "B", "T"};
```

for doing this to an enum

```
public enum BeadColor
{
    BLUE = "P",
    RED = "B",
    GREEN = "T",
    NONE,
}
```

So if this is possible i would like to use the `enum` to check if my string `BigRoadData.Contains(/*the enum BLUE for example*/)`

cause instead of doing the normal way

```
if(BigRoadData.Contains(str[0])){
   //print a
}
```

I would like to do it "IF POSSIBLE" like this

```
if(BigRoadData.Contains(/*the enum blue for example*/)){
   //print a
}
```

## EDIT

**CustomClass.cs**

```
public string BigRoadData = "";
public string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};
public void MakeBigRoad(string data){

    BigRoadData = data;

    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++){
        BigRoadData += strData [i];
        BigRoadData += ",";
    }
}

public void ScoreBoardCondition(){

    if(BigRoadData.Contains(....)){

    }
}
```

**MainClass**

Here i will call it like this

```
CustomClass.ScoreBoardCondition();
```

## EDIT

On my **CustomClass.cs**

```
public enum _Data
{
    P,
    B,
    T,
}

public enum _BeadColors
{
    BLUE,
    RED,
    NONE,
}

public _Data previousColor = _BeadColors.NONE;

class CustomClass{

}

//extension method for contains
public static bool Contains(this string input, _Data data){
string[] str = { "P", "B", "T" };

if(data == BaccaratScoreboard._Data.P){
    return input.Contains (str [0]);
}

if(data == BaccaratScoreboard._Data.B){
    return input.Contains (str [1]);
}

if(data == BaccaratScoreboard._Data.T){
    return input.Contains (str [2]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how BRData is declared and what's inside of it?

Comment: Your code is confusing. Which type is BRData? Are you confusing method OnBeadIncreased with an enum? Please claify.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl I changed the variable from BRData to BigRoadData

Comment: @Programmer I edited it sir . And by the I changed my variable from BRData to BigRoadData

Comment: 1 - You can't use a method like this: `BigRoadData.Contains(OnBeadIncreased.BLUE)`.  2 - What is the relation between "P", "B", "T" values and the `BeadColor`enum?

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl Oh i see . So it is really impossible .

Comment: What is `CustomClass.ScoreBoardCondition();`?

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl I edited it to show you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question it still confusing and lacks information. See [ask] and [mcve]. Also, much of your questions have already good answers. Look here in [so] or google.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl downvoted. Okay thanks anyway for that .

Comment: Black and blue seem like they could be fun. You'll need to parse to enum, so your enum names will have to match, or you'll need to use a dictionary to map values.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Yes. Edit your question to be ansewarble and I will remove the downvote. And try to answer.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl I edited my question .

Comment: @john parse the enum . hmmm `Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors)` like this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/3181933) shows how, but you will need your enum names to match the strings. So you can't parse B as BLUE, for example.

Comment: @john Nice . It was really helpful .

Comment: @Programmer I edited it

Comment: No. That's not the code from my answer. Please copy the code since you are running into issues typing it. The code in the `Contains` function is wrapped around a static `ExensionMethod` class.

Comment: @Programmer Didn't notice that. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

**1**.You can map your `Enum` to the data in the string array with a `Dictionary` then use `Dictionary.ContainsKey(YourEnum.Value)`.

**2**.You make the names of the enum variable the-same with the name of the values in the string array then use  `Enum.Parse` to make this conversion and compare them.

**3**.You can make an `Contains` extension method for the `string` class that hides your `BigRoadData.Contains(str[0])`. This function will take `BeadColor` 
 enum as argument and allows you to compare with that instead of `str[0]`.

I will provide an example for the last method. You can implement the other ones yourself if you wish to use them instead.

The enum:

```
public enum BeadColor
{
    BLUE, //P
    RED,  //B
    GREEN, //T
    NONE,
}
```

The extension method:

```
public static class ExensionMethod
{
    public static bool Contains(this string input, BeadColor cColor)
    {
        string[] str = { "P", "B", "T" };

        if (cColor == BeadColor.BLUE)
            return input.Contains(str[0]);

        if (cColor == BeadColor.RED)
            return input.Contains(str[1]);

        if (cColor == BeadColor.GREEN)
            return input.Contains(str[2]);

        return false;
    }
}
```

The extension method maps "P" to `BeadColor.BLUE`, "B" to `BeadColor.RED` and "T" to `BeadColor.GREEN` and makes it possible to check if the color exists using the `BeadColor` enum.

**Usage**:

It works on string

```
public string BigRoadData = "";

void Start()
{
    if (BigRoadData.Contains(BeadColor.BLUE))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sir ` Unexpected symbol `bool', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', or `struct'` I just tested that out i thought it was working but its not

Comment: Please add EDIT to your question followed by your new code as it is. Do not modify it in any where.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `string`as the type of your `enum`.
You can try `char`, but is not recommended.
See this question and answers: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/8588384/2025364](http://You%20can't%20use%20%60string%60as%20the%20type%20of%20your%20%60enum%60.%20You%20can%20try%20%60char%60,%20but%20is%20not%20recommended.%20See%20this%20question%20and%20answers:%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/8588384/2025364)

By the way, concatenating strings like that is VERY bad:
`BigRoadData += strData [i];`
Use `String.Concat` (or `StringBuilder`) instead.