# How would you create a List<string> out of an enum without following the enum structure of having 'condensed' naming policies?

Tags: list, enums, ienumerable

With an enum like say:

```cs
public enum Authors
{
  KirkPatrick,
  JasmineLliki,
  NatashaKakuvi
}
```

Now using this helper method I can easily get the corresponding `List<string>` values:

```cs
public class EnumHelper<T> where T : Enum
{
    public static List<string> ToList() => Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).ToList();
}
```

My desired output would be something like:

```
new List<string>() {"Kirk Patrick", "Jasmine Lliki", "Natasha Kakuvi"};
```

instead of

```
new List<string>() {"KirkPatrick", "JasmineLliki", "NatashaKakuvi"};
```

that the method outputs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to, effectively, assign string values to Enums.
If that is your intention, check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value), may be one of the cases there will be helpful.

If you want to proceed with your current Enums instead, you can try using answers [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272633/11593686) to add spaces in a string with capital letters.