# What is the best way to implement error code either by Enum or Constant

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, enums

I need to handle error codes for the project. Previously, the enums were implemented like the following

```
enum ErrorCode{
    None=0,
    InvalidUserName = 1,
    InvalidEmail
}
```

Later, we thought to move to some user defined error code like the following.

```
"ERR001", "ERR001" .. etc.
```

For that, I have two options,

- [Using string annotation for the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value)
- Using constants or readonly static.

What is the best way to do either by enum (which does not support string) or constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a numerical value to your error reason enum and prefix it with `ERR`.

```cs
public enum Error
{
    None = 0,
    Duplicate = 1,
    MissingDetails = 2,
    MissingFocus = 3,
    NoSampleCode = 4
}

public static string GetErrorCode(Error error)
{
    return $"ERR{(int)error:D3}";
}

Console.WriteLine(GetErrorCode(Error.NoSampleCode)); // prints "ERR004"
```

If this isn't what you require, you need to provide more information / sample code in your question so we can understand what is needed.