# Complier error if function parameter string is not in allow list

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering is there is some C#\Visual Studio magic where I can have a list of strings that form a allow list for parameter inputs into a function?

In other words I would have a list of strings `[“Green”, “yellow”, “blue”]` and a function `void example(string colour);`. If I try to do `example("red");` I get a complier error.

Bonus point if I can read this list for a text file or something, but copy and paste is fine.

Thanks

EDIT: I have ended up using const string C_RED = "RED".
I never noticed that intellisence will give you a list of const.  This works well as I can just type C_ and it will give me the valid options.

Comment: It almost seem like you're looking for an [*enumeration*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)?

Comment: Find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid but would a enum not change the value to a int? If I did "example(Yellow);" would it not pass "1" as the parameter? I still need to pass the string to the function.

Comment: Can't you convert the enum parameter to a string inside the function? Although even if you were using an enum the compiler would allow you cast an invalid value to the enum without issuing a compile error, e.g. `MyFunc((Color)18797);` (assuming `Color` is an enum)

Comment: So that would not do what I need. I need to make sure the value is vaild before I complie (or run).

Comment: Why does it have to be *strings*? What is the *actual* and *underlying* problem you need to solve? This is really too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in its current state.

Comment: It needs to be a string becuase they are been sent to a telnet session...

Answer (score 0):

Store the string in the list collection. Then take out the corresponding value and pass it to the example method.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> mList = new List<string>(){"Green", "Rellow", "blue"};

        mList.Add("Green");
        mList.Add("Rellow");
        mList.Add("blue");
        new Program().example(mList[2]);

    }

   
    public void example(string colour)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("colour：" + colour);
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

A analogy of the problem I faced and this is how I addressed it.
I want to restrict the Action in a Controller to be executed only if the query parameters in the request has allowed values.

**1. Created a custom Validation Attribute**

```
public class ElementValidate : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string[] element = { "GREEN","YELLOW","BLUE" };

        public override bool IsValid(object? value)
        {
           string user_input =  (value as string).ToUpper();
            if (element.Contains(user_input))
            { 
                  return true;
            }
            else
                return false;   

        }
    }
```

**2. Place the Attribute over the action method for which it is to be checked.**

```
   [ElementValidate]
    public void Sample1()
    {
      // Actual Logic Goes Here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
enum colors {Green=1, yellow=2, blue=3};

void example(string colour)
        {
            //Convert month in enum;
            Enum.TryParse(colour, out colors givenColour);

            if (givenColour == 0)
                throw new Exception("Invalid colur");

            // your implementation
        }
```

[image]