# Override Tostring() of enum to accommodate runtime string changes

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like this

```
enum Animal:byte
{
Cat=0,
Dog=1,
Horse=2
}
```

I want to override the `ToString()` of it to to write a custom string because my application is a multi-language one(`Cat.ToString()` should retrieve the translated word of cat). so the `Description` keyowrd can't be used here.can anyone give me a hint to find a neat way to solve this?

Comment: This is answered very well here: [Enum ToString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring)

Comment: Thanks@JohnWillemse but as far as i know the Description tag should have a fixed string ,can i set a custom string to it?

Comment: something like enumName=GetTranslation(enumName.ToString());

Comment: I think the method using an extension method is more suitable for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWillemse the Extension method worked well :)