# How do I access Enum in MVC4 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have a enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum ResultType {
    Success = 0x01,
    Failed = 0x02,
    Comment = 0x03
}
```

How do I access it in my MVC4 Razor View?  Something like this:

```
You have:  @ResultType.Failed!!!
```

Comment: Have you tried it? That should work unless you need the full namespace

Comment: Indeed, Didn't know about the namespace requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum ToString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring)

Comment: Unrelated note: The `Flags` decorator is out of place, I think, especially because the enumerated value you provide for `Comment` is mutually exclusive to `Success` and `Failed`.

Comment: I use it because it convert the enum as a string instead of an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work fine.
However, you need to import the namespace:

```
@using Some.Namespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @SLacks gave does work, but I'd like to expand on it. I keep all of my app enums in a single file (for maintainability) and you can add the namespace of that (and anything else you consistently need in views) in the ~/Views/Web.Config or other relevant config file. This will allow you to use the enums without having to remember to add the namespaces, and is especially helpful if you are using visual studio scaffolding.

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="YourApp.Enums" />
</namespaces>
```