# Using AddRange with Distinct() is not working with Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, enums, iqueryable

I am trying to filter one of my `enum` fields from my model.  Here's the definition of my `enum`:

```
public enum ProjectDifficulty
{
    Medium,
    High,
    [Display(Name = "Very High")]
    VeryHigh,
    Complex
}
```

But I cannot get the results; I see this error:

> Cannot convert from '`System.Linq.IQueryable<Finder.Models.ProjectDifficulty>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`'

My controller contains this code:

```
var ProjectDifficultyLst = new List<string>();

var ProjectDifficultyQry = from b in db.Projects
                           orderby b.ProjectDifficulty
                           select b.ProjectDifficulty;

ProjectDifficultyLst.AddRange(ProjectDifficultyQry.Distinct());

ViewBag.projectDifficulty = new SelectList(ProjectDifficultyLst);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectDifficulty))
{
    SearchQry = SearchQry.Where(l => l.ProjectDifficulty == projectDifficulty);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cast it to list? If you want to operate on list you should do ProjectDifficultyQry.Distinct().ToList()

Comment: Are you not trying to add an IQueryable of enum to a List<string>?

Comment: @maque I have tried casting to the list but its still showing error saying that invalid arguments. Basically, I am trying to use get the data from the DB and use it as a drop-down search list. But, I am not sure why I am reciving this error about IQueryable. Although, I have another enum in my model and that works fine with search list without any problem.

Comment: `ProjectDifficulty` is typeof `enum`, not `string`. Hard to understand what your trying to do here.

Answer (score 3):

The error message clearly tells you what is wrong. Your `ProjectDifficultyQry` is of type `IQueryable<ProjectDifficulty>`, and you want to add it to a `List<string>`. Of course, you cannot do that. You need to convert your enum values to string. Here's how you do it:

```
var ProjectDifficultyQry = from b in db.Projects
                           orderby b.ProjectDifficulty
                           select b.ProjectDifficulty.ToString();

ProjectDifficultyLst.AddRange(ProjectDifficultyQry.Distinct());
```

By the way, you don't have to use `ToList()`. `IQueryable` is `IEnumerable` (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx)).

One more thing; I don't know how you are using that `DisplayAttribute` in your `Enum`. But, if you want to use "Very High" instead of "VeryHigh" in your `SelectList`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings).

Comment: Hi @ataravai, thanks for your reply. I have managed to get it working by using 'ViewBag.projectDifficulty = new SelectList(ProjectDifficultyQry.Distinct());' however, it does not display all of the fields, it only display medium, high and very high but there is another field as well in the table called Complex but it does not showing in drop down box.  Also, I am trying to filter according to user selection any advice on that?? I am thinking to do something like this  'SearchQry = SearchQry.Where(x => x.ProjectDifficulty = projectDifficulty);'

Comment: @HarshPanchal, do you want all the Project Difficulties to be added to the SelectList or only those that are in the database? If you want all of them, then, why are you querying the database?

Comment: I need Project Difficulties as a SelectList so user can filter based on the selected Project Difficulty.

Comment: @HarshPanchal, you didn't get my question. I know you need it as a SelectList. But, why are you querying the database? Don't you need all the options in your Enum in the SelectList?