# C# Newbie needs help: convert enum to string

Tags: c#, enums

I am a programming novice. I would like to convert ComputerHand and PlayerHand to strings so I can then create an string array to write to a text file.

```
 public enum Hand { Rock = 1, Paper, Scissors };
 public enum Outcome { Win, Lose, Tie };

 public Hand ComputerHand { get; set; }
 public Hand PlayerHand { get; set; }
 public char UserSelection { get; set; }
```

Comment: have you tried ComputerHand.ToString(). See here to iterate through all values : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/enumerate-an-enum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum ToString with user friendly strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings) I use the method outlined here to provide friendly names. The `.ToString()` is fine if all you want is the name as it is defined - but sometimes that doesn't look particularly good if you want to use it in text.

Comment: I did consider mentioning deriving a converter from the TypeConverter class - but maybe not for novices.

Comment: @PaulF it's nice to have the option though.

Comment: Just wanted to say that you may have a Hand array instead of storing all converted strings.  Hand[] myHands;

Answer (score 0):

Given below Enum,

```
public enum AnEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}
```

Short answer: AnEnum.Value1.ToString()

If you want to give a different details (friendlier string) to enum value, you can use "Description" attribute to enum. See this: [How can I assign a string to an enum instead of an integer value in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403065/how-can-i-assign-a-string-to-an-enum-instead-of-an-intereger-value-in-c)

If you are dealing with enum <-> string, you may sometime want to convert string to an enum, which can be done like this:

```
AnEnum AnEnumValue = (AnEnum ) Enum.Parse(typeof(AnEnum ), "Value1", true);
```

Just for someone's benefit who is working with enum ans strings, if you want to make an array of string from enum values,

```
string[] arrayOfEnumStrings 
        = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnEnum)).Cast<AnEnum>()
            .Select(enumVal=> enumVal.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Here, "Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foos)).Cast()" will get you enumurator of enum values. Then "Select" will convert those enum values to string.