# How do I format an Enum?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, enums

I need my enum to return a formatted string to the view, for example:

```
public enum status
{ 
   NotStarted,
   InProgress,
}
```

return: `Not Started` and `In Progress`. How I do it? Thanks (language C#)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings

Comment: I've just added my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings/33921043#33921043) to linked question, which is nice example of [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) usage.

Answer (score 2):

enums don't do that. You'd need to provide a map of enum values to display strings or you could do something like define an attribute with a display string that you can use (which requires some fiddly reflection to get the attribute for a given enum value, but has the advantage that you can define the display name right where you define the enum value).

For example, you can use a `Dictionary<status,string>` to map them:

```
var myMap = new Dictionary<status,string>()
{
    { status.NotStarted, "Not Started" },
    { status.InProgress, "In Progress" }
};
```

Now to get the display string for a given status value `s` you'd just do something like:

```
var s = status.NotStarted;
var displayString = myMap[s];   // "Not Started"
```

Of course, you'd put this in a class somewhere so it's only defined once in one place.

Another rather brittle, quick-and-dirty way to do it would be to exploit the fact that your enum names are Pascal-cased and use something like a regex to take the enum name and insert an extra space. But that's pretty hacky. So you could do something like:

```
var r = new Regex("([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)");
var displayString = r.Replace(s.ToString(),"$1 $2");    // "Not Started"
```

But that would choke on any enum values that didn't fit the pattern of two Pascal-cased words. Of course, you could make your regex more flexible, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToString` on an emum value is the equivalent to [Enum.GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) which would give you the named value i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine(status.NotStarted.ToString()) // NotStarted
```

From there, assuming the format is consistent, you could convert the string from Pascal casing to a whitespace separated string e.g.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(status.NotStarted, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
Console.WriteLine(result); // Not Started
```

[See example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D537gv)

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.GetName(typeof (Status), Status.InProgress));
```