# Method of storing strings other than List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, poker

I'm developing a poker app and currently I want to store all the card combinations names I'm planning to use list and do something like this :

```
private static List<string> combinationNames = new List<string>
{
    " High Card ",
    " Pair ",
    " Two Pair ",
    " Three of a Kind ",
    " Straight ",
    " Flush ",
    " Full House ",
    " Four of a Kind ",
    " Straight Flush ",
    " Royal Flush ! "
};

for (int j = 0; j < combinationNames.Count; j++)
{
    if (current == j)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Have : ", combinationNames[j]);

    }
}
```

So is there a better way of storing those names and later access them like I did ?

Comment: Define "better". What is causing you a problem at the moment?

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Mb simply `combinationNames[current]`?

Comment: there is actually no current i just wrote this i do some other checks before it also there's no problem with my code im asking for a better way of storing those strings instead of putting them in the list

Comment: But "better" really depends on what you ultimately end up doing with the rest of your code. This is probably something you will be best to just do, then learn from experience.

Comment: You can use Dictionary or HashSet. Look here for more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You've still not defined what you mean by better. Its kind of like asking if there is a better tool than a hammer - it very much depends if you are driving nails or turning screws

Comment: by better i mean more compact .. English is not my native language so i thought that they have a similar meaning

Comment: @kopelence Just get on with your poker game, and see how it pans out.

Comment: All of those plays have a value (at least, some of them "weight" more than others), so would recommend using a Enumeration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/479453/335905

Comment: Yea i was thinking exactly for enum but im not sure if it's going to do any better

Comment: The higher hurdle will be detecting those correctly in hands.  Since you wont be adding to the list over time, this is a case where an array would work just fine

Comment: Well i actually have this already im doing a win method and i want to print the winner + the hand this list is just so i dont need to do `if(current==1)` etc

Comment: @kopelence I would go with a Dictionary, then I can access the hand by a well-defined name.

Comment: An unrelated note on things: there's no difference between a straight flush and a royal flush; a royal flush is merely the highest straight flush you can have. So, my opinion is that for the same reason you don't (in this list) distinguish between a K-high straight flush and a 5-high straight flush, there's no reason to distinguish between an A-high straight flush and any other.

Comment: This is not the method for checking combinations it's just a message box shower so in case you got royal flush it's quite rare and i just want to notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to go on in your question to understand what's specifically wrong with the code you have. That said, at the very least I would expect the following to be an improvement:

```
private readonly static string[] combinationNames =
{
    " High Card ",
    " Pair ",
    " Two Pair ",
    " Three of a Kind ",
    " Straight ",
    " Flush ",
    " Full House ",
    " Four of a Kind ",
    " Straight Flush ",
    " Royal Flush ! "
};

if (current >= 0 && current < combinationNames.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Have : ", combinationNames[current]);
}
```

I.e.:

- Since the list won't change, it can be an array instead of a list
- Since the list *object* won't change, the variable can be `readonly`
- All the code you did does with `j` is compare it to `current`; there's no need to enumerate every possible value for `j`…just make sure `current` is within the valid range and then use its value directly.

Note on that last point it's not really clear where you get `current` from, but likely it should already be guaranteed to be valid before you get as far as displaying the text, so you shouldn't even really need the range check. I just put that there to ensure the new version of code above is reasonably consistent with the behavior of the code you showed (what little was there).

If you need more specific advice than the above, please explain more precisely what you think would be "better" and in what way the code you have now is not sufficiently addressing your needs. I.e. what does the code do now and how is that different from what you want it to do?