# How To override enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums, overriding

I write enum with custom ToString() method
example

```
  public enum MyEnum{
        a,
        b,
  }
  My = MyEnum.a;
  Console.Write(My.ToString); // ---> output : aaaaa
```

and in code `My.ToString()`
Do you have idea ?

Comment: You can't directly do it in C#, but there's plenty of workaround to choose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple technich if you dont need complex string, is to have 2 enum collection

```
public enum MyEnum1{
    a,
    b,
}

public enum MyEnum2{
    aaaaa,
    bbbbb,
}

var My = MyEnum.a;
Console.Write((MyEnum2)My).ToString()) // ---> output : aaaaa
```

Comment: Your answer was interesting

Comment: the comment of Marteen is good too but more complex with attributes..another way if you have complex string is to create dictionary<enum, string>