# C# Enum with description not working

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Enum from Description attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute)

Hi All, 
 I have and Enum defined like this.

```
public enum SomeType {
        [Description("One Value")]
        One,
        [Description("Two Value")]
        Two,
        [Description("Three Value")]
        Three       
    }
```

but when I try to parse a string like this

```
SomeType  test =  (SomeType )Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeType ), "Three Value");
```

I get excetion "Requested value 'Three Value' was not found". Isn't this supposed to work ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually using `SomeType`?

Comment: [Check out this entry. Certainly what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. You can find the Enum by the enum Name ("One", "Two", "Three"), but not by Description (at least not that way). Maybe via Reflection...

You might wanna take a look at this: [How to get C# Enum description from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-enum-description-from-value)

**Update**

Take a look at @KIvanov's comment and look here: [Get Enum from Description attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute)

Comment: Actually Parse should recognize the Name ("Three"). But not the description.

Comment: I had edited my answer. I had written "cannot", but it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know

```
SomeType  test =  (SomeType )Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeType ), "Three");
```

would do what you want

Comment: Not really, OP wants to get Enum by the Description, not name. BTW I did not downvote.