# Can enums contain strings?

Tags: c#, string, enums

How can I declare an `enum` that has strings for values?

```
private enum breakout {            
    page = "String1",
    column = "String2",
    pagenames = "String3",
    row = "String4"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have said, no you cannot.

You can do static classes like so:

```
internal static class Breakout {
    public static readonly string page="String1";
    public static readonly string column="String2";
    public static readonly string pagenames="String3";
    public static readonly string row="String4";

    // Or you could initialize in static constructor
    static Breakout() {
        //row = string.Format("String{0}", 4);
    }
}
```

Or

```
internal static class Breakout {
    public const string page="String1";
    public const string column="String2";
    public const string pagenames="String3";
    public const string row="String4";
}
```

Using readonly, you can actually assign the value in a static constructor. When using const, it must be a fixed string.

Or assign a [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) to enum values, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute).

Comment: I'd use make them readonly or const as well.

Comment: +1 Although `const` would be better than `static` in this case.

Comment: @vcsjones & @Davy - Good points. I had meant to include readonly but missed it.

Comment: +1 for the description attribute.

Answer (score 20):

No they cannot.  They are limited to numeric values of the underlying enum type.

You can however get similar behavior via a helper method

```
public static string GetStringVersion(breakout value) {
  switch (value) {
    case breakout.page: return "String1";
    case breakout.column: return "String2";
    case breakout.pagenames: return "String3";
    case breakout.row: return "String4";
    default: return "Bad enum value";
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good one with the helper method!

Comment: `ToString("F")` is useful for formatting to the name of the enum value, if they don't want custom strings.

Comment: A note with the switch: if you leave out the default case, then if you update the enum with new values the compiler will warn you the switch needs to be updated too. This can be handy.

Comment: @Chris I don't believe that is the case.  Without the `default` label the C# compiler will only warn / error about the lack of return on all code execution paths

Comment: Yup I was in my own little world there. Just tried what I was mentioning and now I can't remember what exactly I was thinking of.

Comment: @Chris I believe certain tools like R# or FxCop may provide this behavior.  Can't remember for sure though

Comment: Thanks @Jared Par let me resort to your solution..

Comment: The default case should throw an exception.

Comment: @JaredPar Neat! A dynamic + generic version would be nice. Take in a `dictionary<userenum,string>` and csharp or IL-Emit this ultraperformant version. Perhaps someone has already implemented something like that?

Answer (score 8):

No, but you can get the enum's value as a string:

**[Enum.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx)**

```
private enum Breakout {     
  page,
  column,
  pagenames,
  row
}

Breakout b = Breakout.page;
String s = b.ToString(); // "page"
```

Answer (score 2):

An enum has integer as underlying type by default, which is also stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on msdn.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Enum.GetName()/Enum.GetNames()` can be helpful for you.

Comment: These methods work via reflection. At that point one might as well use assembly metadata, which is slow to access.
One of the reasons for Enums are their performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of enums.

```
public enum OrderType
{
    ASC,
    DESC
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<OrderType, string> MyDictionary= new Dictionary<OrderType, string>()
                                                     {
                                                         {OrderType.ASC, ""},
                                                         {OrderType.DESC, ""},
                                                     };
}
```