# Using EnumMemberAttribute and doing automatic string conversions

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code

```
[DataContract]
public enum StatusType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "A")]
    All,
    [EnumMember(Value = "I")]
    InProcess,
    [EnumMember(Value = "C")]
    Complete,
}
```

I'd like to do the following:

```
 var s = "C";
 StatusType status = SerializerHelper.ToEnum<StatusType>(s);   //status is now StatusType.Complete
 string newString = SerializerHelper.ToEnumString<StatusType>(status);   //newString is now "C"
```

I've done the second part using DataContractSerializer (see code below), but it seems like a lot of work.

Am I missing something obvious? Ideas? Thanks.

```
    public static string ToEnumString<T>(T type)
    {
        string s;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, type);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        using (var xml = new XmlTextReader(s, XmlNodeType.Element, null))
        {
            xml.MoveToContent();
            xml.Read();
            return xml.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've like this option because it extends Enum: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4367868/1243316

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is my proposition - it should give you the idea on how to do this (check also [Getting attributes of Enum's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value)):

```
public static string ToEnumString<T>(T type)
{
    var enumType = typeof (T);
    var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, type);
    var enumMemberAttribute = ((EnumMemberAttribute[])enumType.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true)).Single();
    return enumMemberAttribute.Value;
}

public static T ToEnum<T>(string str)
{
    var enumType = typeof(T);
    foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
    {
        var enumMemberAttribute = ((EnumMemberAttribute[])enumType.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true)).Single();
        if (enumMemberAttribute.Value == str) return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
    }
    //throw exception or whatever handling you want or
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

If your project references [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) (what doesn't these days?!), then there is a simple one line solution that doesn't need reflection:

```
public static string ToEnumString<T>(T value)
{
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value).Replace("\"", "");
}

public static T ToEnum<T>(string value)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>($"\"{value}\"");
}
```

The `ToEnumString` method will only work if you have the `StringEnumConverter` registered in your `JsonSerializerSettings` (see [JavaScriptSerializer - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/net-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)), e.g.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new StringEnumConverter() }
};
```

Another advantage of this method is that if only some of your enum elements have the member attribute, things still work as expected, e.g.

```
public enum CarEnum
{
    Ford,
    Volkswagen,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Aston Martin")]
    AstonMartin
}
```

Comment: There is an overload for `string JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object? value, params JsonConvert[] converters)`. So `ToEnumString` can be changed to: `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new StringEnumConverter()).Replace("\"", "");`

This negates the need to register the converter separately.

Comment: A great addition to the proposed solution and avoiding the need to register another convertor - works a treat!

Answer (score 9):

Using extensions and C# 7.3 constraints

```
    public static class EnumMemberExtensions
    {
        public static string ToEnumString<T>(this T type)
            where T : Enum
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);
            var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, type);
            var enumMemberAttribute = ((EnumMemberAttribute[])enumType.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true)).Single();
            return enumMemberAttribute.Value;
        }

        public static T ToEnum<T>(this string str)
            where T : Enum
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);
            foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
            {
                var enumMemberAttribute = ((EnumMemberAttribute[])enumType.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), true)).Single();
                if (enumMemberAttribute.Value == str) return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
            }
            //throw exception or whatever handling you want or
            return default;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a .net core solution equivalent to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to get the value of the `EnumMemberAttribute`.

```
public static string ToEnumString<T>(T instance)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("instance", "Must be enum type");
    string enumString = instance.ToString();
    var field = typeof(T).GetField(enumString);
    if (field != null) // instance can be a number that was cast to T, instead of a named value, or could be a combination of flags instead of a single value
    {
        var attr = (EnumMemberAttribute)field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();
        if (attr != null) // if there's no EnumMember attr, use the default value
            enumString = attr.Value;
    }
    return enumString;
}
```

Depending on how your `ToEnum` works, you might want to use this sort of approach there as well.  Also, the type can be inferred when calling `ToEnumString`, e.g. `SerializerHelper.ToEnumString(status);`

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how to convert enums using the `DescriptionAttribute`, the `EnumMemberAttribute` and the property name:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

```cs
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static T ToEnumByAttributes<T>(this string value)
            where T:Enum
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);
            foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
            {
                var field = enumType.GetField(name);
                if(field == null) continue;

                var enumMemberAttribute = GetEnumMemberAttribute(field);
                if (enumMemberAttribute != null && enumMemberAttribute.Value == value)
                {
                    return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
                }

                var descriptionAttribute = GetDescriptionAttribute(field);
                if (descriptionAttribute != null && descriptionAttribute.Description == value)
                {
                    return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
                }

                if (name == value)
                {
                    return (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, $"The value could not be mapped to type {enumType.FullName}");
        }

        public static string ToStringByAttributes(this Enum value)
        {
            var field = value
                .GetType()
                .GetField(value.ToString());

            if (field == null) return string.Empty;

            var enumMemberAttribute = GetEnumMemberAttribute(field);
            if (enumMemberAttribute != null)
            {
                return enumMemberAttribute.Value ?? string.Empty;
            }

            var descriptionAttribute = GetDescriptionAttribute(field);
            if (descriptionAttribute != null)
            {
                return descriptionAttribute.Description;
            }

            return value.ToString();
        }

        private static DescriptionAttribute? GetDescriptionAttribute(FieldInfo field)
        {
            return field
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }

        private static EnumMemberAttribute? GetEnumMemberAttribute(FieldInfo field)
        {
            return field
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false)
                .OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

NUnit Tests:

```cs
    [TestFixture]
    public sealed class EnumExtensionsTests
    {
        public enum TestEnum
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "A")]
            Alpha,

            [Description("O")]
            Omega
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldSerialize_FromEnumAttribute()
        {
            var result = TestEnum.Alpha.ToStringByAttributes();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("A"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldSerialize_FromDescriptionAttribute()
        {
            var result = TestEnum.Omega.ToStringByAttributes();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("O"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldDeserialize_FromEnumAttribute()
        {
            var result = "A".ToEnumByAttributes<TestEnum>();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(TestEnum.Alpha));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldDeserialize_FromDescriptionAttribute()
        {
            var result = "O".ToEnumByAttributes<TestEnum>();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(TestEnum.Omega));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldDeserialize_FromPropertyName()
        {
            var result = "Alpha".ToEnumByAttributes<TestEnum>();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(TestEnum.Alpha));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the [Reefact.JsonEnumValueBinding library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Reefact.JsonEnumValueBinding) because I mostly use Json instead of Xml nowdays. Would this be suitable? ?

```cs
public enum StatusType {
    [JsonEnumValue("A")] All,
    [JsonEnumValue("I")] InProcess,
    [JsonEnumValue("C")] Complete,
}
```

So you can do the following:

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { Converters = { new JsonEnumValueConverterFactory() } };

string     s                  = "C";                                                         // s is "C"
StatusType deserializedStatus = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StatusType>($"\"{s}\"", options); // status is now StatusType.Complete
string     serializedStatus   = JsonSerializer.Serialize(deserializedStatus, options);       // serializedStatus is now "\"C\"" 
string     newString          = serializedStatus[1..^1];                                     // newString is now "C"
```

Unfortunately, Json serialization introduces quotation marks, but perhaps this doesn't pose any real problems for you in your real-life use case?