# Search within Enum attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I want to check in Enum that passed code exists in any of enum or not. Problem is my enum defined is like below with using code attribute.

```
public enum TestEnum
    {

        None,

        [Code("FMNG")]
        FunctionsManagement,

        [Code("INST_MAST_MGT")]
        MasterInstManagement
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CodeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        readonly string _code;
        public string Code
        {
            get
            {
                return _code;
            }
        }
        public CodeAttribute(string code)
        {
            _code = code;
        }
    }
```

Now, I have string available (e.g. "FMNG") and I want to search that enum back that enum exists with passed string which will be in enum attribute.

How can I check/get that enum using or passing string? I tried with using `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ActivityEnum), "FMNG")` but it is not working with attributes of enum.

Comment: Can you use `Description` attribute instead of `Code` in `enum`  ?

Comment: Actually code is predefined and there are 50+ enums so I cannot change code attribute now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic function:

```
    public static object ToEnum(string codeToFind, Type t)
    {
        foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(t))
        {
            CodeAttribute[] codes = (CodeAttribute[])(enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString()).
            GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeAttribute), false));

            if (codes.Length > 0 && codes[0].Code.Equals(codeToFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                enumValue.ToString().Equals(codeToFind, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return enumValue;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Usage:             `var test = ToEnum("INST_MAST_MGT", typeof(TestEnum));`

The above function will return the `Enum` value if it finds the defined `Code` attribute or the `codeToFind` parameter is equal to Enum's value ToString, you can adapt it by your needs.

Comment: If you made your method generic, it could have the signature `public static T ToEnum<T>(string codeToFind) where T : struct`. Note that if the enum defines several constants with the same numerical value, `Enum.GetValues` is not a good choice.

Comment: The return type is `Object` to be able to return null value if the Code is not found, it seams easier this way.

Comment: If you really want that, you can return a nullable `T`, also known as `T?`. Or you could use the try-get pattern: return `bool` and use an `out` variable of type `T` for the result.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be an idea to do away with the attribute altogether and create a static dictionary for the codes:

```
static Dictionary<string, TestEnum> codeLookup = new Dictionary<string, TestEnum>() { 
                                                     { "FMNG" , TestEnum.FunctionsManagement }, 
                                                     { "INST_MAST_MGT", TestEnum.MasterInsManagement } };
```

Then just do

```
bool isDefined = codeLookup.ContainsKey("FMNG");
```

This may well be faster than using reflection each time to loop up the attribute, but it depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
public TestEnum GetEnumByAttributeName(string attributeName)
{
    foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestEnum)))
    {
        var memInfo = typeof(TestEnum).GetMember(item);
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Count()> 0 && ((CodeAttribute)attributes[0]).Code == attributeName)
            return (TestEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestEnum), item);
    }
    return TestEnum.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public static T GetEnumValueByAttributeString<T>(string code) where T : struct
{
  if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    throw new ArgumentException("T should be an enum");

  var matches = typeof(T).GetFields().Where(f =>
    ((CodeAttribute[])(f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeAttribute), false))).Any(c => c.Code == code)
    ).ToList();

  if (matches.Count < 1)
    throw new Exception("No match");
  if (matches.Count > 1)
    throw new Exception("More than one match");

  return (T)(matches[0].GetValue(null));
}
```

Like you see, it checks if the string you come with is ambiguous. Use it like this:

```
var testEnum = GetEnumValueByAttributeString<TestEnum>("FMNG");
```

If performance is an issue, you might want to initialize and keep a `Dictionary<string, T>` of all the "translations", for quick lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I found generic method below:

```
public static T GetEnumValueFromDescription<T>(string description)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (!type.IsEnum)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
            var field = fields.SelectMany(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(
                                typeof(CodeAttribute), false), (
                                    f, a) => new { Field = f, Att = a })
                            .Where(a => ((CodeAttribute)a.Att)
                                .Code == description).SingleOrDefault();
            return field == null ? default(T) : (T)field.Field.GetRawConstantValue();
        }
```

Source: [Get Enum from Description attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute)