# Class design: Access two keys as properties using a constant?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, class-design

**Now:**

2 classes each with the same constant name, e.g. ERR123

class1 got `public const int ERR123 = 123;`

class2 got `public const string ERR123 = "Error 123, something went wrong.";`

So I call it like

```
int code = class1.ERR123;
string message = class2.ERR123;
```

I don't like this approach because I need to copy the constant names and touch 2 files when I add/change something.

**I'd like to access it like that:**

```
int code = Errors.Subcategory1.ERR123.Code; 
string message = Errors.Subcategory1.ERR123.Message;
```

and the declaration shouldn't be that inconvenient. Is this possible? Maybe using some reflection-magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To descript message codes with descriptions you can use enum with Descrition attribute. [Get Enum from Description attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Why make something more complex than it needs to be?

```
public class Errors
{
     public static class IntegerErrors {
          public const string ERR123 = 123;
      }

     public static class StringErrors {
         public const string ERR123 = "Error 123, something went wrong.";
     }
}

...

int i_value = Errors.IntegerErrors.ERR123;
string s_value = Errors.StringErrors.ERR123;
```

Comment: That is more or less what I have now.