# Use enum to show message boxes

Tags: c#, enums, messagebox

Is it possible to show a MessageBox according to the selected enum item? E.g.:

```
public enum Messages
{
    UserAlreadyExists,
    NoUserName,
    NoPassword,
    NoUserNameOrPassword
}
```

If so, how do I handle each item in order to show a specific MessageBox?

Comment: What did you try? A simple `switch` might work?

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know how to assign tasks to enum items mate, could you please show me an example?

Comment: @Alan_UK `switch(val){case UserAlreadyExists: MessageBox.Show("User already exists"); break; case NoUserName: MessageBox.Show("No user name"); break; }`?

Comment: @GSerg, seems like it might work, but where should I put that `switch` statement and what should I put inside the `()`? I'm sorry, I'm new to enums

Comment: obviously where you need it and what for

Comment: Or [decorate values with attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2650080/11683).

Comment: If you own the enumeration, consider renaming it. A plural is supposed to indicate a flags enum which this is not. It doesn't seem to be a message either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two alternative approaches for you to consider.

The obvious solution: a simple [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement:

```
var msg = Messages.NoPassword;
switch (msg)
{
    case Messages.NoPassword:
        MessageBox.Show("No password");
        break;
    case Messages.NoUserName:
        MessageBox.Show("No user name");
        break;
    case Messages.NoUserNameOrPassword:
        MessageBox.Show("No user name");
        break;
    case Messages.UserAlreadyExists:
        MessageBox.Show("User already exists");
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, add [[Description] attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the enumeration values (assuming the enum is not defined in third party code):

```
MessageBox.Show(GetDescription(msg));
```

For which you'll need [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4367723/397817):

```
public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute attribute
            = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute))
                as DescriptionAttribute;

    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
}
```

and each enumeration member will need to be decorated:

```
public enum Messages
{
    [Description("User already exists")]
    UserAlreadyExists,
    [Description("No user name")]
    NoUserName,
    [Description("No password")]
    NoPassword,
    [Description("No user name")]
    NoUserNameOrPassword
}
```

Neither of these solutions are localised of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
switch(input_value) 
{
case Messages.UserAlreadyExists: 
MessageBox.Show("User already exists");
break;
}
```