# Where should I store error definitions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing my own identity system for my ASP.Net 5 application, and I am currently looking for an efficient way to store my predefined error codes and their corresponding descriptions.  Does anyone have any suggestions to my issue?

Comment: How are these 'error codes' to be used? Anyway .. I would probably start with an enum and [put the description in attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value). This is because the error codes [probably] are *a fixed set* that are intrinsically part of the code itself, with the description coming along for the ride. Resolving the enum value to description would be tucked away in some DI-Service so that even if the descriptions were resolved via not-attributes later there would be no code change at the usage sites.

Comment: Well an error code is represented as a string; for example, "PasswordInvalid".

Comment: An enum represents values. The string represents a value (where each 'error code string' would represent a specific error). Then consider the trivial mapping: `enum ErrorCode { PasswordInvalid, AccountLocked }`. Anyway, do you really use the *string* to represent the error code? And if so, *why*?

Comment: Relevant if using a enum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use resource files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

They allow you to store the name of the error code, the error code and a description. Then use Properties.Resources to access them.