# C# Enum Reverse Indexing

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to use an integer index to return the appropriate value from an enum?  For example, if there is the enum Color {Red, Green, Blue) is there a function that for the value 0 will return Red, 1 will return Green, and 2 will return Blue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get C# Enum description from value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-enum-description-from-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Enum.GetName method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx

Using your example,

```
Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(Color), 1));
```

prints "Green"

Comment: Note that if you obfuscate your code, you will get jibberish instead of a human readable name. In that case, write your own translation method.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your integer value to an enum.

```
Color c = (Color)0; //Color.Red
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string color = ((Color)1).ToString(); //color is "Green"
```

Use the Enum.ToString() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's klunky but...

```
String Day = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), 3);
```