# is there any easy solution to make enum dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I created a simple dropdown list using the following code

Model:

```
    public enum weltype 
    {  
        Physical = 1, 
        Career =2
    }
```

controller:

```
            IEnumerable<weltype> Wellbeings = Enum.GetValues(typeof(weltype))
                                                  .Cast<weltype>();
            model.WellList = from welbeing in Wellbeings
                             select new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Text = welbeing.ToString(),
                                 Value = ((int)welbeing).ToString()
                             };
            return View(model);
```

view:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WellbeingID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WellbeingID, Model.WellList)
```

my problem here is i need to get the enum values from the database using linq or whatever feasible. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: This is how to get the enum string from the corresponding enum value: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2650080.  Are you sure you don't want to include `weltype` as a table in the database, so that you can just do a simple join/lookup?

Comment: weltype is a table in a database, i dont need enum string but i need to get weltype values from the database instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: If all you want is an IEnumerable, why not use a Dictionary?