# Convert Enum with [DescriptionAttribute] to Dictionary<string,int>

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I have this Enum

```
public enum Genders
    {
        [Description("Nữ")]
        Female,
        [Description("Nam")]
        Male
    }
```

I use this code to get each Enum name and value and save it to an Dictionary
The result is

Female : 0

Male :1

```
    accountViewModel.Genders = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Account.Genders))
                               .Cast<Account.Genders>()
                               .ToDictionary(t => t.ToString(), t => (int)t);
```

How to mofify above code to get each Enum's Description and it value ?

Like this.

Nữ : 0

Nam : 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650090/643095,

```
string description = Enumerations.GetEnumDescription((MyEnum)value);
```

Where `value` is `int` enum value.

You can use something like this:

```
accountViewModel.Genders = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Account.Genders))
                               .Cast<Account.Genders>()
                               .ToDictionary(t => Enumerations.GetEnumDescription((Genders)t), t => (int)t);
```