# VB.NET rename Enums for Combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, enums, rename

I'm stuck and I hope someone can help me.
I want to change my Enum Items name so they are displayed different in the Combobox.

```
Public Enum Conditions
    VeryGood
    Good 
    JustOkey
    Poor
End Enum
```

In my Main:

```
ComboBox_Cond.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(Conditions)))
ComboBox_Cond.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
ComboBox_Cond.SelectedIndex = CInt(Conditions.JustOkey)
```

In my combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Cond_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox_Cond.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox_Cond.Items.Add(Conditions.VeryGood).ToString("Very good")
    ComboBox_Cond.Items.Add(Conditions.Good).ToString("Good")
    ComboBox_Cond.Items.Add(Conditions.JustOkey).ToString("Just okey")
    ComboBox_Cond.Items.Add(Conditions.Poor).ToString("Poor")
End Sub
```

The result of this is just as you can imagine, I got both the "raw" Enum names and the ToString names in my combobox list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ComboBox_Cond.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(Conditions)))` should populate with just the names unless you have other code doing something (like the second code block),  the selection can be converted back using `Enum.Parse` very simply

Comment: Sorry if was unclear. I just want the combobox to display the ToString names, as "Very good" instead of "VeryGood".

Comment: @Televinken: Did you check my answer? Looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: See [How to get C# Enum description from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value) or [C# - How to Display Friendly Names for Enumerations](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2487/c---how-to-display-friendly-names-for-enumerations) to use attributes and extensions to accomplish a similar goal. Those are both obviously for C# though, so you'd have to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a (key,value) pair, so the easiest would probably be creating a dictionary:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Conditions, String)
With dict
  .Add(Conditions.VeryGood, "Very good")
  '...
  .Add(Conditions.Poor, "Poor")
End With
```

Then use data binding instead of `ComboBox_Cond.Items.AddRange`:

```
ComboBox_Cond.ValueMember = "Key"
ComboBox_Cond.DisplayMember = "Value"
ComboBox_Cond.DataSource = dict.ToList
```

You can then access the `Conditions` value using `ComboBox_Cond.SelectedValue`.

Comment: Thank you @Neolisk. I'm kind of new to this, where do I write the Dictionary, in the top of my Main Class?

Comment: @Televinken: You don't need it as a class variable, from what I see in your code. You can put it **instead** of `ComboBox_Cond.Items.AddRange` and see if it works. `ComboBox_Cond.SelectedValue` will get you `Conditions` value, which I think you are after. The point here is that you don't have to convert back, it will be done by .NET for you.