# How can i save an enum in my context in EF code first version 6

Tags: c#, enums, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Hi I need to save a single enum in my context, I tryed this:

```
  public class Context : DbContext
  {
      public Context() : base("name=Context"){}

      MyEnum MyEnum  { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Object1> Objects{ get; set; }

}
```

, when I modify MyEnum it changes its value but after saving changes when I want to use it goes back to the enum of value 0. Heres my modification code:

```
 MyEnum example = MyEnum.Value1;
 using (var ctx = new Context())
        {
            ctx.CriterioPlanificacion = example;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What SQL is being generated? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this old question I made, so i tested it.
The migrations after adding a enum to the DbContext are empty, so EF doesnt saves the ints in a DbContext.

Microsoft documentation recommends only using DbSets that only exposes DbSets with collections of TEntities in it

Answer (score 0):

Enum default type is an int. It is normal that the value is 0 because it is the first element. If you want to put a description for your elements you can use the description attribute and retrieve it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value).

Comment: In the database and in the memory the enum is saved like an int i know, but my problem is that the conext method SaveChanges() isnt changing my db

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the Enum field had property "StoreGeneratedPattern" with value = "Computed". After changing to 'None' - everything started working correctly.

Comment: If you have a question just use Ask Question or provide a good solution for the user