# How to change a database value in asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I have a simple database over a hotel, this is for a cleaning service so I have a column named "status", this column has type int and are defined as 0 when a new room is added to database.

Problem is I would like the output of this column's value to be "Not cleaned" instead of "0". And "Cleaned" if the value is "1".

Any idea of how I can do this in the easiest way possible? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way? Change the boolean to a varchar in the database....

Comment: Is that an int or a bit? How are you displaying? Did you want to change the database or just display a value? What is your code? I answered the question, but my answer makes way more assumptions than I would like because of your bad question.

Comment: Well, as I said in my question: It's an int and, as I also mention in my (bad) question, I want the value to be displayed as a text instead of an int. I want the value to be change in database from 0 to 1 IF the user change the "status", but I don't want the database to store the value as a varchar. I don't have any code yet, that's why I asked this question. I often code in PHP and I would like a solution like "if (status == 0) { echo "Not cleaned"; } else if (status == 1) {echo "Cleaned"; }".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the database is storing these as a `bit` not an `int` you can do the following:

```
string Cleaned = row["status"]?"Cleaned":"Not Cleaned"
```

Then use the string as you wish.

If you want to actually change the DB, that takes more work, you'd have to create a new column (or change the existing one, even harder) for the string value as a `VARCHAR(15)` (only really need 11 but I pad to be safe) then update that based on the bit in your old column.

```
UPDATE {Table} SET {NewColumn}=IIF(status=1,'Cleaned','Not Cleaned')
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Way, not the most correct design but the easiest

```
public enum RoomStatus : int
{
    NotCleaned = 0,
    Cleaned = 1
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var e1 = (RoomStatus)0;
    var e2 = (RoomStatus)1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using entity framework and you are referencing storing an enum.

If this is correct, check this link:
[How to save enum in database as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542356/how-to-save-enum-in-database-as-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [OLEDB connection](http://asp.net-informations.com/data-providers/asp-oledb-connection.htm) after this you have to use SQL [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) command. This will look like this :

```
UPDATE your table name SET status='Cleaned' WHERE status=1;
```

Comment: And what happens when you get an error due to the type mismatch? It's more likely status is an int or bit than a varchar, and even then it may not fit the 11 characters, if they wrote it to store the number.