# Entity Framework / SQL Server: Enums are saving in database as numeric values rather than strings despite using HasConversion<string>()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have configured various entities in my `DbContext` class to convert the enum value to a string when saving to the database eg.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestObject>(builder =>
{
   builder.ToTable("TestObject", "test");
   builder.Property(x => x.MyEnum).HasConversion<string>();
}
```

However all of these enum values are being saved as the numeric value behind the enum.

I've tried checking the strings aren't being truncated by the max lengths on the columns in the database but the enum string values are definitely all valid lengths.

At this point I'm not sure where else to check, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What type is the column in database?

Comment: Did you check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542356/how-to-save-enum-in-database-as-string

Comment: @Rafalon it's varchar(20) and the longest string value in the enum is 8 characters long

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using a stored procedure for the insert and didn't realise I was passing the enum value to the SQL parameter in as `MyTestEnum.TestValue`.

Passing in `MyTestEnum.TestValue.ToString()` as the SQL parameter fixed the issue.