# I need a elegant way to extract alternate data from an enum

Tags: c#, enums, compact-framework

I was looking for a way to get an alternate value from an enum, and referenced this answer

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986749/5122089

Here it uses a description attribute to assign a value and then a method for extracting that as so

> ```
> public static string DescriptionAttr<T>(this T source) {
>    FieldInfo fi = source.GetType().GetField(source.ToString());
>
>     DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
>         typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
>
>     if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0) return attributes[0].Description;
> else return source.ToString(); }
> ```

Only I'm unfortunately stuck in the dark ages with .net 3.5 Compact Framework, and do not appear to have access to System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute

Might anyone give me a hint how to get something like this working...

Comment: You can easily implement your own custom attributes, which is what you may need to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for. I just did some changes on the original code:

```
static class MyClass
{
    public static string DescriptionAttr<T>(this T source, Type attrType, string propertyName)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = source.GetType().GetField(source.ToString());

        var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            var propertyInfo = attributes[0].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(attributes[0], null);
                return value as string;
            }
        }
        else
            return source.ToString();

        return null;
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Name1 = 1,
    [MyAttribute("Here is another")]
    HereIsAnother = 2,
    [MyAttribute("Last one")]
    LastOne = 3
}

class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute(string desc)
    {
        Description = desc;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var x = MyEnum.HereIsAnother.DescriptionAttr(typeof(MyAttribute), "Description");
```

Comment: Indeed this gets me exactly what I'm looking for.  I very much appreciate you taking the time to demonstrate.

Comment: the attributes[0] isn't elegant to have there. You might want to change that somehow or not. Mark the question as valid, please

Comment: indeed I have refactor​ed the answer greatly but it has enlightened me on how to apply custom attributes as well as reflect and dig out information.  I thought I'd let it sit a bit and see what others come up with