# Alter Enumeration Menu Name Format [C#]

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums, console-application

I'm having an issue with formatting how I specifically want to display the enumeration items to the console window.

As of right now the Menu method displays the items in the enumeration as follow:

```
[1] CreateCustomer
[2] CreateAccount
[3] SetAccountBalance
[4] DisplayAccount Balance
[5] Exit
```

What I'm trying to accomplish well be to add the appropriate spaces between each menu option. For example,
"CreateCustomer" to "Create Customer", "SetAccountBalance" to "Set Account Balance".

Menu Selection Enumeration

```
enum MenuSelection
{
   CreateCustomer = 1,
   CreateAccount = 2,
   SetAccountBalance = 3,
   DisplayAccountBalance = 4,
   Exit = 5,
   MaxMenuSelection = 5,
}
```

Display Menu Method

```
public static void Menu()
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= (int)MenuSelection.MaxMenuSelection; i++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {((MenuSelection)i).ToString()}");
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the description attribute, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary` the `key`  is `MenuSelection` and the `value` contain your customer display string.

```
Dictionary<MenuSelection, string> dict = new Dictionary<MenuSelection, string>();
dict.Add(MenuSelection.CreateCustomer, "Create Customer");
dict.Add(MenuSelection.CreateAccount, "Create Account");
dict.Add(MenuSelection.SetAccountBalance, "Set Account Balance");
dict.Add(MenuSelection.DisplayAccountBalance, "Display Account Balance");
dict.Add(MenuSelection.Exit, "Exit");

string showValue = string.Empty;
for (int i = 1; i <= (int)MenuSelection.MaxMenuSelection; i++)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue((MenuSelection)i, out showValue))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] { showValue}");
    }           
}
```

Comment: What did your previous implementation look like?

Comment: @NTaveras What's your mean about  previous implementation?

Comment: When I saw your response it looked different to what it looks now.

Comment: Before I used dictionary key get value  `Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] { dict[(MenuSelection)i]}"); `, but `TryGetValue` will be better than it.

Comment: note that this localizes whereas the enum based versions do not (maybe not important for you , but its a major difference)

Answer (score 1):

One way is using the Display Attribute:

```
enum MenuSelection
{
   [Display(Name = "Create Customer")]
   CreateCustomer = 1,
   [Display(Name = "Create Account")]
   CreateAccount = 2,
   ...
}
```

But getting its value is not as easy as it should be. you can find it in [How to get the Display Name Attribute of an Enum member via MVC razor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code)

Another way that I use it myself is a function I have written that adds an space before each capital letter:

```
public static class Exts
{ 
    public static string CapitalSplit(this string x)
    {
         return Regex.Replace(x, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2").Trim();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= (int)MenuSelection.MaxMenuSelection; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {((MenuSelection)i).ToString().CapitalSplit()}");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the Description attribute (or Display attribute).  Here I used an extension method to make it a little easier:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= (int)MenuSelection.MaxMenuSelection; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {((MenuSelection)i).GetEnumDescription()}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(this MenuSelection m)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = m.GetType().GetField(m.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : m.ToString();
    }
}

public enum MenuSelection
{
    [Description("Create Customer")]
    CreateCustomer = 1,
    [Description("Create Account")]
    CreateAccount = 2,
    [Description("Set Account Balance")]
    SetAccountBalance = 3,
    [Description("Display Account Balance")]
    DisplayAccountBalance = 4,
    Exit = 5,
    MaxMenuSelection = 5,
}
```

Result:

```
[1] Create Customer
[2] Create Account
[3] Set Account Balance
[4] Display Account Balance
[5] Exit
```

Comment: What is FieldInfo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    enum MenuSelection
    {
        CreateCustomer = 1,
        CreateAccount = 2,
        SetAccountBalance = 3,
        DisplayAccountBalance = 4,
        Exit = 5,
        MaxMenuSelection = 5,
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Enum
            .GetNames(typeof(MenuSelection))
            .Select(name => new 
            { 
                name, 
                index = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(MenuSelection), name, true) 
            })
            .Select(kv => $"[{kv.index}] " + String.Join(" ", SplitByCamelCase(kv.name)))
            .Select(item => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                return true;
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public static bool IsLower(char ch) 
    {
        return ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z';
    }

    public static string Head(string str)
    {
        return new String(
                    str
                        .Take(1)
                        .Concat(
                            str
                                .Skip(1)
                                .TakeWhile(IsLower)
                        )
                        .ToArray()
                );
    }

    public static string Tail(string str)
    {
        return new String(str.Skip(Head(str).Length).ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByCamelCase(string str) 
    {
        if (str.Length == 0) 
            return new List<string>();

        return 
            new List<string> 
            { 
                Head(str) 
            }
            .Concat(
                SplitByCamelCase(
                    Tail(str)
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[1] Create Customer
[2] Create Account
[3] Set Account Balance
[4] Display Account Balance
[5] Exit
[5] Max Menu Selection
```

[See sample online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2X97DT)

Answer (score 0):

This is very quick and dirty.  However, it has the advantage that you can create any menu with any `enum` type.

It separates words based on case (upper/lower) transitions.  It works, except for your MaxMenuSelection.  Instead of putting that in your enum, make it a template (on an enum type) function that return GetValues().Length (see below):

The `where` shown below is `where T : struct` because the compiler I'm using doesn't support `where T : System.Enum` which would be much better, but requires the latest compiler.

```
  public static string SeparateWords(string enumName)
  {
      var buffer = new StringBuilder();
      var wasLower = false;
      foreach (var c in enumName)
      {
          if (wasLower && char.IsUpper(c))
          {
              buffer.Append(' ');
          }

          buffer.Append(c);
          wasLower = char.IsLower(c);
      }

      return buffer.ToString();
  }

  public static void DisplayMenu<T>() where T : struct //should be System.Enum if possible
  {
      var enumType = typeof(T);
      var names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
      var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType) as int[];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; ++i)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"[{values[i]}] {SeparateWords(names[i])}");
      }
  }
```

I get this output:

```
[1] Create Customer
[2] Create Account
[3] Set Account Balance
[4] Display Account Balance
[5] Exit
[5] Max Menu Selection
```

When I call this:

```
 EnumTest.DisplayMenu<MenuSelection>();
```

And, you can get the "Max Menu Selection" by doing this:

```
public static int MaxMenuSelection<T>() where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not do something simple and add an _ in between the words?

Then you can do this:

```
    enum MenuSelection
    {
        Create_Customer = 1,
        Create_Account = 2,
        Set_Account_Balance = 3,
        Display_Account_Balance = 4,
        Exit = 5,
        MaxMenuSelection = 5,
    }
    public static void Menu()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= (int)MenuSelection.MaxMenuSelection; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {((MenuSelection)i).ToString().Replace("_"," ")}");
        }
    }
```

You get this as a result:

```
 [1] Create Customer
 [2] Create Account
 [3] Set Account Balance
 [4] Display Account Balance
 [5] Exit
```