# How to obtain the Name parameter in tables with Enum, used ej2.syncfusion and asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

How to show the Name parameter in tables with ej2.syncfusion and asp.net core?

My model is:

```
public class MyEntity
    {

        public int ID;
        
        public enum StateEnum
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "State A")]
            [Display(Name = "State A")]
            A = 0,
            [EnumMember(Value = "State B")]
            [Display(Name = "State B")]
            B= 1
        }

   public StateEnum StateEnum{ get; set; }

}
```

I get the data in the controller to feed the table:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var myEntities= _context.MyEntities.ToList();
            return View(myEntities);
        }
```

In View I use a GRID with ej2.syncfusion:

```
<ejs-grid id="Grid" dataSource="@Model" allowPaging="true" allowFiltering="true" allowSorting="true">
    <e-grid-filterSettings type="Menu"></e-grid-filterSettings>
    <e-grid-pagesettings pageSize="4"></e-grid-pagesettings>
    <e-grid-columns>
        <e-grid-column headerText="ID" field="ID" textAlign="Right" width="120" isPrimaryKey="true"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column headerText="StateEnum" field="StateEnum" textAlign="Right" width="120" ></e-grid-column>
       
    </e-grid-columns>

</ejs-grid>
```

I get a table as a result:

```
ID | StateEnum
----------------
1  | 0
2  | 1
```

But I wanted to get the display names from the enumeration:

```
ID | StateEnum
----------------
1  | State A
2  | State B
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value). Or you can use static class instead of enum.

```
public static class StateEnum
{
    public const int A = 0;
    public const int B = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query we understand that you want to display the names (State A and State D instead of A and B) from the enumeration. To achieve this requirement we suggest converting Enum to string value using **Newtonsoft decorator (StringEnumConverter)** like below. Refer to the below code example.

```
public long ID;     
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
            
public StateEnum StateEnum { get; set; }
```