# How to assign my Enum description value to a variable? I'm new to this

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have this Enum class with descriptions

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Hero.Core.Enum
{
    public enum HeroResultCode
    {
        [Description("Successfully Completed!")]
        Successful = 0,
        [Description("Username Already Exist")]
        UsernameAlreadyExist = 1
    }
}
```

Error class for storing enum values.

```
    {
    public class Error
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }}
```

How should I assign the "Enum Description string" to "_error's string "Message""?

```
     if (resultCode != HeroResultCode.Successful)
            {
                _error = new Error
                {
                    Code = resultCode.ToInt32(),
                    Message = ,
                };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get C# Enum description from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

Comment: See also https://github.com/xin9le/FastEnum

Answer (score 1):

To get Description you have to use method : `GetEnumDescription`
For e.g :

```
 if (resultCode != HeroResultCode.Successful)
            {
                _error = new Error
                {
                    Code = resultCode.ToInt32(),
                    Message = Enumerations.GetEnumDescription((HeroResultCode)resultCode),
                };
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, had to create a function of GetEnumDescription to use that. Thanks again.