# HTTP GET Return List Enumeration .Net Core

Tags: c#, enums, http-get

I have an `enum` and values ​​in it. I want to get list of these values ​​with get method. I just started and I don't know how to do it.

```
public enum NotificationTemplateType
{
    [Description("Şablonsuz")] NotTemplate = 0,

    // User Şablonları - 100
    [Description("Yeni Kullanıcı Şablonu")] NewUser = 100,
    [Description("Şifremi Unuttum Şablonu")] ForgotPassword = 101,

    // Seller Şablonları - 200 
    [Description("Yeni Satıcı Şablonu")] NewSeller = 200,
}

[HttpGet("GetType")]
    public List<IActionResult> GetType(NotificationTemplateType notificationTemplateType)
    {
        return Ok(notificationTemplateType.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description);
    }
```

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values of an enum via [GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationTemplateType))
```

Since this returns an array and you want a list, you can just call the `ToList` method:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationTemplateType)).ToList()
```