# Is there some trick in C# to give some value a name?

Tags: c#

I came from C/C++, and used alot things like `#define OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS 2`, so that when coding actual logic you can have `state = OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS;`, and what it does become more obvious than `state = 2;`, which makes the code easier to maintain.
I wonder if there is some trick like this in C#

Comment: Are you looking for: const int ObjStateInProgress = 2; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though technically a different concept, in C# you can use contants and enums to avoid "magic numbers", e.g.

```
public static class Constants
{
  public const string MyConst = "ThisIsMyConst";
}

public enum MyEnum
{
  MyEnumValue1, 
  MyEnumValue2,
}

// Usage
var value = MyEnum.MyEnumValue2;
```

Comment: Please mark your Constants class as static otherwise it could be instantiated.

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for the hint - forgot about that when typing. I have changed the sample.

Comment: ok, although the `MyEnum.` or `Constants.` part would still looks a little messy, but I think I can live with it.

Comment: @Qian2501: In what way _messy_? `enum States{ InProgress = 2; }` Somewhere else: `state = States.InProgress;`. Is that messy? You can even give enums a [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value) message, in case you want to output more than `InProgress` or `2`.

Comment: i dont get the need of an enum plus a static class with constants. are you looking for a way to define a constant and call it from anywhere ?

Comment: `OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS` is cleaner than `StateEnum.OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS` when there is a lot of code, also you don't need `StateEnum.` part to understand what it does. But I think it's more of my C/C++ habit though,  just a minor detail

Comment: @Qian2501, sure `StateEnum.OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS` is less clean. But honestly, who exactly is preventing you with all their might from creating/using something like `ObjState.Inprocess` or similar? I want to have a serious word with them...

Comment: Ah, thanks Tim, your way of naming looks better in C# context.

Comment: Haha, it's just getting a enum value dont need to specify the name of the enum in C/C++, or it's more often defined as a macro, so we always name it as such, but C# is different, just habit thing

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using constant properties, for example:

```
static class Constants
{

    public const int OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS = 2
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine(Constants.OBJ_STATE_INPROCESS ); //prints 2
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a property. It is just a field.

Comment: in C #define PROPERTY 2 is a constant, in terms of maintainability i believe this is what he is looking for.Just have a constant and call it from anywhere