# How to add space in enum in visual studio bot framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, enums

I used data annotations, but it did not work. I used 
`[Display(name=" you want to know about products")]`

but it didn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is not in-built or direct method to add a space in enumerator properties in c#. But you can use the following workaround.

This will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57716964/9524580