# C# explicit cast string to enum

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, enums, casting

I would like to have an explicit cast between from a string to an enum in c# in order to have this :

```
(MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),stringValue)
```

I would like to deport this into an explicit cast operator, I did this but didn't work :

```
public static explicit operator (MyEnum)(value stringValue){
     return (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),stringValue);
}
```

Do you know if it's possible in C# using .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A cast is not possible. The issue is that a user-defined conversion must be enclosed in a struct or class declaration, and the conversion must be to or from the enclosing type. Thus,

```
public static explicit operator MyEnum(string value)
```

is impossible because neither `MyEnum` nor `string` can ever be the enclosing type.

The relevant section of the ECMA334 C# spec is 17.9.4:

A conversion operator converts from a source type, indicated by the parameter type of the conversion
operator, to a target type, indicated by the return type of the conversion operator. A class or struct is
permitted to declare a conversion from a source type S to a target type T only if all of the following are true,
where S0 and T0 are the types that result from removing the trailing ? modifiers, if any, from S and T:

S0 and T0 are different types.

**Either S0 or T0 is the class or struct type in which the operator declaration takes place**.

Neither S0 nor T0 is an interface-type.

Excluding user-defined conversions, a conversion does not exist from S to T or from T to S.

However, you can do an extension method on the string class.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static T ConvertToEnum<T>(this string value)  {
        Contract.Requires(typeof(T).IsEnum);
        Contract.Requires(value != null);
        Contract.Requires(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value));
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I knew I had seen it somewhere and didn't remember how to work this out. Thanks!

Comment: Great extension!  A lot of times people forget to make sure that the value is defined in the enum.

Comment: @Gromer I feel it's worth mentioning that .Net 4.0 added a method for that very reason `Enum.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 9):

Is it necessary to use a cast operator? Another option would be to add an extension method off of string:

```
public static class StringEnumConversion
{
    public static T Convert<T>(this string str)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "StringValue" attributes for get what you want.

Check out this question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums), there's plenty of info there that might help.

cheers