# string representation of an enum (estring)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

i need an enum or something similiar to do something like this:

> public enum MyStringEnum {
>   [StringValue("Foo A")] Foo = "A",
>   [StringValue("Foo B")] Foo = "B" }

is this possible? my example, i return back a dataset with a value represented as either A,B,C,D,E .. i need a solution to return this as a string representation?

i guess the obvious would be to create an extension method or something which just had a switch statement in and return a string .. any other cleaner solutions?

regards,
dave

Comment: I should point out that the underlying values for enums cannot be strings. `The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: I would like to point you to the Mark's answer... much elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# String enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be an option not to use enum and use structs instead?

```
struct FooEnum
{
    private int value;
    private string name;
    private FooEnum(int value, string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static readonly FooEnum A = new FooEnum(0, "Foo A");
    public static readonly FooEnum B = new FooEnum(1, "Foo B");
    public static readonly FooEnum C = new FooEnum(2, "Foo C");
    public static readonly FooEnum D = new FooEnum(3, "Foo D");

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    //TODO explicit conversion to int etc.
}
```

You could then use FooEnum like an enum with an own ToString() overload:

```
FooEnum foo = FooEnum.A;
string s = foo.ToString(); //"Foo A"
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is something we use for our MVC applications to retrieve a display name for our enums.  It uses a custom attribute and an extension method to retrieve the enum display name.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
  public EnumDisplayNameAttribute(string displayName)
  {
    DisplayName = displayName;
  }

  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}


public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumType)
{
  var displayNameAttribute = enumType.GetType()
                                     .GetField(enumType.ToString())
                                     .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                     .FirstOrDefault() as EnumDisplayNameAttribute;

  return displayNameAttribute != null ? displayNameAttribute.DisplayName : Enum.GetName(enumType.GetType(), enumType);
}
```

Usage on the enum:

```
public enum Foo
{
  [EnumDisplayName("Foo Bar")]
  Bar = 0
}
```

Getting back the display name:

```
var f = Foo.Bar;
var name =  f.GetDisplayName();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like this:

```
MyStringEnum value = MyStringEnum.A;
string description = value.GetDescription();
// description == "Foo A"
```

Setup your enum like this:

```
public enum MyStringEnum
{
    [Description("Foo A")]
    A,
    [Description("Foo B")]
    B
}
```

And use a utility/extension method that reads the attribute:

```
public static string GetDescription(this MyStringEnum enumerationValue)
{
    Type type = enumerationValue.GetType();
    string name = enumerationValue.ToString();

    //Tries to find a DescriptionAttribute for a potential friendly name for the enum
    MemberInfo[] member = type.GetMember(name);
    if (member != null && member.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attributes = member[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            //Pull out the description value
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done where I would put

```
MyStringEnum.Foo.ToString();
```

In this case it would give "A"

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution for this problem is to create a custom attribute that will store the string value you want for the enum constant. I've used that strategy in the past and it worked out fairly well. Here's a blog post detailing the work involved:

[Enum With String Values In C# - Stefan Sedich's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx)

Of course this is only necessary if you need some kind of meaningful text. If the name of the enum constant works for you...then you can simply call `ToString()`.