# enum with space property for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, enums

since i can not have space in enum and i am trying to do something like this but seems like does not like it....

```
public enum EnumState
{
    NewYork,
    NewMexico
}


public EnumState State
    {
        get
        {
            return EnumState ;
        }
        set
        {
            if (EnumState .ToString() == "NewYork".ToString())
            {
                value = "New York".ToString();
                EnumState = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (EnumState == EnumState.NewYork)`

Comment: Setting the value of `value` in a setter is a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToString()` on strings?  What do you intend to accomplish by assigning a string value to an enum typed variable?  Whatever you are trying to do, there is probably a better way of approaching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this generally handled by putting a `[StringValue("New York")]` attribute on the enum members. A quick google search returns [this blog post,](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx) which has a pretty good way of doing it.

Basically make the attribute class:

```
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute {

    public string StringValue { get; protected set; }

    public StringValueAttribute(string value) {
        this.StringValue = value;
    }
}
```

And an extension method to access it:

```
   public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value) {
        // Get the type
        Type type = value.GetType();

        // Get fieldinfo for this type
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

        // Get the stringvalue attributes
        StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

        // Return the first if there was a match, or enum value if no match
        return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].StringValue : value.ToString();
    }
```

Then your enum would look like this:

```
public enum EnumState{
  [StringValue("New York")]
  NewYork,
  [StringValue("New Mexico")]
  NewMexico,
}
```

and you can just use `myState.GetStringValue();`

Comment: If you need exact string analogue why just not to call EnumState.NewYork.ToString() ?

Comment: @sll - Because `New York` has a space. `NewYork` doesn't.

Comment: A better improvement on this would be to use the existing `DisplayNameAttribute` and extend it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this pattern : [C# String enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-string-enums/424414#424414)

It will allow you to define a custom string name for every enum you have in your enumeration.