# Mvc Html.DropDownList on load replace some string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've have this Dropdown that is generated by my Enum

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyType",
EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(C_Survey.Models.QuestionType)),
"Select My Type",
new { @class = "form-control N_Q_type" })
```

Enum:

```
public enum QuestionType {
    Single_Choice,
    Multiple_Choice,
    Range
}
```

My question is, how can I replace the `_` with a space ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much details of `GetSelectList` method there, but I assumed it receives a `System.Enum` and returning a `SelectList` collection like this:

```
public static SelectList GetSelectList(this Enum enumeration)
{
    var source = Enum.GetValues(enumeration);
    // other stuff
    ...

    return new SelectList(...);
}
```

There are 2 approaches to solve this issue:

**First Approach (Using Custom Attribute)**

This approach involves creating a custom attribute to define display name (set attribute target to field or others which fit to entire enum members):

```
public class DisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DisplayName { get; protected set; }
    public DisplayNameAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.DisplayName = value;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Hence, the enum structure should be modified to this:

```
public enum QuestionType 
{
    [DisplayName("Single Choice")]
    Single_Choice,

    [DisplayName("Multiple Choice")]
    Multiple_Choice,

    [DisplayName("By Range")]
    Range
}
```

Later, it is necessary to modify `GetSelectList` method to accept custom attribute created above which includes `DisplayName` property:

```
public static SelectList GetSelectList<T>(this T enumeration)
{
    var source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

    var items = new Dictionary<Object, String>();
    var displaytype = typeof(DisplayNameAttribute);

    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)field.GetCustomAttributes(displaytype, false).FirstOrDefault();

        items.Add(value, attr != null ? attr.GetName() : value.ToString());
    }

    return new SelectList(items, "Key", "Value");
}
```

**Second Approach (Using Direct Type Cast & Lambda)**

Similar to first approach, `GetSelectList` method will return `SelectList` from an `enum`, however instead of using custom attribute this approach uses member names to build select list items as shown below (`T` is enum type parameter):

```
public static SelectList GetSelectList<T>(this T enumeration)
{
    var source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { 
        Text = x.ToString(),
        Value = x.ToString().Replace("_", " ")
    });

    return new SelectList(source);
}
```

Probably `GetSelectList` method contents in your side is slightly different, but the basics should be same with those approaches.

Similar issues:

[How do I populate a dropdownlist with enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705330/how-do-i-populate-a-dropdownlist-with-enum-values)

[Display enum in ComboBox with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102022/display-enum-in-combobox-with-spaces)

[enum with space property for dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390303/enum-with-space-property-for-dropdownlist)