# How to somehow define enum type as float or double in c#

Tags: c#, enums

It says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) that the possible types for an `enum` are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

What if I need a `float` or a `double` to define percentage increments such as `1.5` or `2.5` for example? Am I stuck?

As said here:
http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_Type_Design_Guidelines%E2%80%94Enum_Design

> An enum is a structure with a set of static constants. The reason to
>   follow this guideline is because you will get some additional compiler
>   and reflection support if you define an enum versus manually defining
>   a structure with static constants.

Since an enum is a set of constants, why can't I have float constants ?

Update: it is said here:
http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_Type_Design_Guidelines%E2%80%94Enum_Design
"Did you know that the CLR supports enums with an underlying type of float or double even though most languages don't choose to expose it?"

Since I'm only using c# is there a way to do so with some hacks ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If you want double constants, an enum is not the right approach...

Comment: An enum is a set of constants, by default it's integer constants, why can't I have float constants ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/424414/313705) out.

Comment: @ChrisF - Not sure about the person asking the question, but in my case, I want to have a function which only takes in the numbers 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, and 0.75. They correspond to the directions North, East, South, and West. I'd like to make it clear that they should be passed by name, and hide that they have a float value as an implementation detail (used for some Quaternion math inside the function.) I guess I'll just make them the `int`s 0, 1, 2, 3, and multiple them by 0.25 inside the function instead, though...

Comment: It's not cool when somebody asks for a feature and other users reply things like "you don't need that". Just stay on point and answer "yes, it's possible like this" or "no, not possible". F.i. I need an enum to hold Earth radii in different cities. There you go, the reason. And there are uncountable such reasons...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the CLR itself supports floating point enums, C# designers chose not to expose this in the language (see http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_Type_Design_Guidelines%E2%80%94Enum_Design). You can either use constants as in John Saunders' answer, or you can define an integer enum with multiplied values and then divide them back if/when you need the value.

The use case would be definitely interesting, though. Why do you need/want this?

Comment: I want to define some fixed increments in percentage that are not integer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As It says "Did you know that the CLR supports enums with an underlying type of float or double even though most languages don't choose to expose it?" since I'm only using c# is there a way to do so ?

Comment: @user310291: No, unfortunately you're stuck with the workarounds posted. You cannot use floating point enums from C#, and I doubt you would really want to write IL directly just to have this feature...

Comment: you guess well I won't write IL directly just to have this feature because I wouldn't know how to :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you're stuck there. You can't use `enum`s with floating-point types. You can use a `static class` with constants, however:

```
public static class MyFloatEnum {
    public const float One = 1.0;
    public const float OneAndAHalf = 1.5;
    // etc.
}
```

And it will look somewhat close in IntelliSense. Alternatively, you may just want to use constants:

```
public const float A = 0.5;
public const float B = 17.62;
```

Comment: Yes I can define a static class but as said here http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_Type_Design_Guidelines%E2%80%94Enum_Design with enum  you will get some additional compiler and reflection support if you define an enum versus manually defining a structure with static constants.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use a set of constants:

```
public const float Percentage1 = 1.5;
public const float Percentage2 = 2.5;
```