# How to reference a database registry of a domain table on C# code?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database-design

My question is :

I have a domain table in database, where I add some rules for users.

Something like this:

Table UserRoles:

```
idRule cRuleDescription bRuleIsActive
1   Edit client      true
2   Delete client    false
```

My C# application refers to this table using enumeration, like this :

```
public enum UserRoles: int
{
    CanEditClient = 1,
    CanDeleteClient = 2,
    CanChangeClientName = 3,

    //More code
}
```

And I use a C# method that query the database, by its Id, to know if the logged user has permission for some action. Something like this:

```
bool HasPermissionToEdit = Rules.UserHasPermisson(UserName, UserRoles.CanEditClient)

if(HasPermissionToEdit)
{
  //Do the work!
}
```

But using this gives me some trouble. Someone created new rows in a production eviroment on database. And the ids are not correct anymore. And I'll need to change the enumeration on my C# code. I need to use this table because, administration users can manage the rules for other group of users.

How do you work with it? There is a better way to reference a registry on a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the rule ID to map to an enum is not crazy in itself as long as the rule ID is not automatically generated (i.e. not an identiy column).

Comment: Yes. I see to much developers doind it. I am one of them. But I think it's not secure. Because someone can change database and the map will get wrong. But I don't see other way to accomplish this.

Comment: You will always have to map to something, it might be the ID it might be the description or another string field.  You will always have a problem with the fact that you have one piece of data in a dynamic system (DB) and one piece in a static system (Code).  Mapping to an integer field is tidy because you can cast the field to your enum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement this properly, make the key contain the name of the role. That way, there cannot be accidents with the ID's where someone thinks the key is meaningless. Naming it idRule does not help.

Second, add a check constraint to enforce correct usage of role names.

Third, add a unique key constraint on the name of the role to enforce that each role only occurs once.

You can use string enums to convert from the role names to integers if you want to. See [C# String enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums) for a nice design pattern.

Example table:

ID - NAME - DESCRIPTION - IS_ACTIVE
1 - CanEditClient - client - true
2 - CanDeleteClient - client  - false
3 - CanChangeClientName - client  - true

Then make sure to add a unique constraint to NAME and a check constraint as well.

Now, no matter how someone shuffles the ID's, your code will continue to work.