# Java-Enums- How to create with default values and access them

Tags: java, enums, primitive-types

i have a java enum which have to have some default values like

```
for the 

String some default values
int some degault values

etc
```

i have created a enum like the following

```
package com.hexgen.tools;

    public enum DefaultParamsValues {
       STRING ("HEXGEN"),
INTEGER(2013),
DATE(new org.joda.time.LocalDate()),
BOOLEAN(true),
BIGINTEGER(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)),
LONG("1898.48");
private  String defaultString;
private  int defaultInteger;
private  LocalDate defaultDate;
private  boolean defaultBoolean;
private  long defaultLong;
private  BigInteger defaultBigInteger;
public DefaultParamsValues(String strValue,int intValue,LocalDate date,boolean booleanValue,long longValue,BigInteger bigintVlaue){
    this.defaultString = strValue;
    this.defaultInteger = intValue;
    this.defaultDate = date;
    this.defaultBoolean = booleanValue;
    this.defaultLong=longValue;
    this.defaultBigInteger = bigintVlaue;
}
    }
```

but it is giving so many issues, would some one help me to create a enum with basic values for primitive types?

EDIT: this is how i solved it:

```
package com.test.poc;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public enum DefaultParamValues {
    STRING("HEXGEN"),
    INTEGER(123),
    DATE(new LocalDate()),
    BOOLEAN(true),
    LONGVALUE(123123),
    BIGINTEGER(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));



    private  String defaultString;
    private  int defaultInteger;
    private  LocalDate defaultDate;
    private  boolean defaultBoolean;
    private  long defaultLong;
    private  BigInteger defaultBigInteger;

    private DefaultParamValues(String strDefaultValue) {
        defaultString = strDefaultValue;
    }
    private DefaultParamValues(int intDefaultValue) {
        defaultInteger = intDefaultValue;
    }
    private DefaultParamValues(LocalDate dateDefaultValue) {
        defaultDate = dateDefaultValue;
    }
    private DefaultParamValues(boolean booleanDefaultValue) {
        defaultBoolean = booleanDefaultValue;
    }
    private DefaultParamValues(long longDefaultValue) {
        defaultLong = longDefaultValue;
    }
    private DefaultParamValues(BigInteger bigIntegerDefaultValue) {
        defaultBigInteger = bigIntegerDefaultValue;
    }
    public String getDefaultString() {
        return defaultString;
    }
    public int getDefaultInt() {
        return defaultInteger;
    }
    public LocalDate getDefaultDate() {
        return defaultDate;
    }

    public boolean getDefaultBoolean() {
        return defaultBoolean;
    }
    public long getDefaultLong() {
        return defaultLong;
    }
    public BigInteger getDefaultBigInteger() {
        return defaultBigInteger;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you look at the type-safe-enum pattern? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/424414/1275256)

Comment: Anto, this looks like a code smell... how/where are you going to use this enum?

Comment: Tassos Please have a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an enum is probably not right for your purpose. You should use a final Class with constants.

But if you want it inefficient and cumbersome you could do it this way:

```
public enum GenericEnum {
    STRING("HEXGEN"), 
    INTEGER(2013), 
    DATE(new Date()), 
    BOOLEAN(true), 
    BIGINTEGER(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)), 
    LONG("1898.48");


    private String defaultString;
    private int defaultInteger;
    private Date defaultDate;
    private boolean defaultBoolean;
    private long defaultLong;
    private BigInteger defaultBigInteger;

    GenericEnum(Object value) {
        if(String.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
            this.defaultString = (String) value;
        } else if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
            this.defaultInteger = (Integer) value;
        }
            [...]
    }
}
```

or overload the constructor:

```
private GenericEnum(String val) {
    this.defaultString = val;
}

private GenericEnum(int val) {
    this.defaultInteger = val;
}
[...]
```

Comment: So looking at the answer it is better to go with constants ??

Comment: Definitely. It's type safe and easy to retrieve a value.

Comment: Good than it is fine to go with Constants, thanks for spending your valuable time. your approach for enum also works good.+1