# Associating a String With a Specific Integer Value

Tags: c#, string, list, enums

I want to be able to associate everything in my program with the original integer that it is found as, but in the end, I want to be able to output a specific string based on that integer number. Right now all of the integers that are found by my program are added to a list, so I was wondering if there was a way that I could use a foreach() loop for each item T in that list and then add a corresponding string to another list.

Is there a way I can do this with Enums or any other build in functions in c#? Ideally, I would want something that looks like this:

```
public enum Tools
{
    tool1 = 1001,
    tool2,
    tool3,
    tool4
}

foreach (int T in ToolList)
{
    //I want to get the enum value based on which int value is passed.
    strToolList.add((int).Tools); 
}
```

I think I would then be able to later convert the tool names to strings for output with a separate function, but if anyone knows how to do that while accomplishing this as well, that would be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To convert enum to int, do `(Tools)T`

Comment: Did you try googling this? There are already hundreds of questions on SO about enums.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# String enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums)

Comment: @BradM I have googled it and looked all over this site, but I have not been able to put together a method that actually does what I want. I want to add a corresponding enum (or ideally string value) to another list based on which int value is found. I know that the enums are associated with a string, but I didn't find a way to essentially "call" them based on their int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (int T in ToolList)
{
   strToolList.add(Enum.GetName(typeof(Tools), (Tools)T)); 
}
```

Comment: Now is there a way that I can use this to point to the Description of the enum, and not just the enum's name?

Comment: What do you mean with Description of the enum?