# Enumeration As String

Tags: c#, string, enums, int

```
enum ValidationMessages
{
    C01_OOHArrestRequired = "Test",
    Trivial,
    Regular,
    Important,
    Critical
};
```

I have the above code. I want to be able to create enums which I can use but are strings not integers.

This is so I can show same string in the UI for validation errors and then test for them in my unit tests and have the messages coming from the same place (been static).

But it says "Cannot convert string to int"

How to have `enum` as strings?

Comment: Then, don't use enums. Use a class with a bunch of constants.

Comment: See this interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an `enum` of type `string`, as `enums` are value types (byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong).

Instead create a static class with const fields:

```
public static class CardiologyValidationMessages
{
    public const string C01_OOHArrestRequired = "OOH Arrest is required when 1 or more Procedures Performed has IsCoronary = True"
}
```

Comment: Does this have roughly the same performance as ENUM? E.g. no major performance impact?

Comment: No performance impact. Compiler may inline the strings the same way the enum values are inlined. You app has better places to improve performance than enum usages.

Comment: Thanks! 100% Best/Simple answer.

Comment: @LmC, of course, there are other benefits to an `Enum` but, if you don't need those, this is the way to go.

Comment: @Jodrell - what are the other benefits?

Comment: An integer requires less storage than this and most strings. The items within an enum have an inherent orderability.

Comment: Is the context you've added to your answer just an inspired guess or is there an earlier question somewhere?

Comment: @Jodrell - That was the string in the first version of the question, it was edited later on I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

What you can do is have a dictionary that maps an enum to an error message: `Dictionary<CardiologyValidationMessages, string>`

Answer (score 1):

["An enumeration is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, you could write a conversion function.

```
string ToValidationMessageString(ValidationMessage value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case C01_OOHArrestRequired:
            return "Test";

        default:
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

or some such.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how to have enum as strings?

You cannot.

From the C# Language Specification Version 5 (supplied with Visual Studio 2013) section 4.1.9

> An enumeration type is a distinct type with named constants. Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which must be byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long or ulong.

However you can apply an [`DisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a name to the values of the enumeration and then use the usual reflection methods to get the name for a given value.